# How to make C# use int method overload for enum types?

Tags: c#, enums, overloading

I got a class in C# that has multiple overloads for different parameter types:

```
class Writer
{
  public Writer Write(bool value)
  {
    // Do something with value
    return this;
  }
  public Writer Write(double value)
  {
    // Do something with value
    return this;
  }
  public Writer Write(int value)
  {
    // Do something with value
    return this;
  }
  public Writer Write<T>(T value) where T : class, IInterface, new()
  {
    // Do something with value
    return this;
  }
}

class Reader
{
  public Reader Read(out bool value)
  {
    // Retrieve value
    return this;
  }
  public Reader Read(out double value)
  {
    // Retrieve value
    return this;
  }
  public Reader Read(out int value)
  {
    // Retrieve value
    return this;
  }
  public Reader Read<T>(out T value) where T : class, IInterface, new()
  {
    // value = new T() or null
    return this;
  }
}
```

Now I want to call `Write` and `Read` for multiple variables in a row, one of which is of an `enum` type. However, that enum type causes difficulties in the method resolving. (Btw: I am used to VB.NET, where `Enum` types are compatible to `Integer` parameters.)

```
enum MyEnum : int
{
  Foo = 0, Bar = 1
}

class CallingClass
{
  public void Call()
  {
    bool b;
    double d;
    int i;
    IInterface o;
    MyEnum e = MyEnum.Foo;

    var w = new Writer();

    // Unintuitive for Write
    w
      .Write(b)
      .Write(d)
      .Write(i)
      .Write(o)
      .Write((int) e);

    // w.Write(e); // resolves to Writer.Write<T>(T)
    // => Compile error: "MyEnum has to be reference type to match T"

    // Even worse for Read, you need a temp variable
    // and can't use fluent code anymore:

    var r = new Reader();
    r
      .Read(out b)
      .Read(out d)
      .Read(out i)
      .Read(out o);
    int tmp;
    r.Read(out tmp);
    e = (MyEnum) tmp;
  }
}
```

Is there any way I can modify `Write`/`Read`, `Writer`/`Reader` or `MyEnum` so that `w.Write(e)` will automatically resolve to `Writer.Write(int)` and more importantly `r.Read(out e)` to `Reader.Read(int)`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/79126/create-generic-method-constraining-t-to-an-enum?rq=1

Comment: this seems to be a maintainable nightmare.

Comment: An output parameter with a `void` return seems like it is an anti-pattern.  Is there a reason why you chose this approach over a `GetAsBool`, `GetAsInt`, `GetAsDouble`, ... series of methods with the corresponding return types?

Comment: @DanielA.White Declaring the int variable is maintainable if you called the method once. Actually I call them very often, so my methods have a fluent interface, so I cannot declare `v` inline or re-use that helper variable. Regarding linked question: this is not possible, since I cannot create a second overload `SetTo<T>` with a different type restriction.

Comment: @erdomke The pattern fell prey to the code stripping, actually the methods have a fluent interface.

Comment: What about going for `Get(out Enum value)`

Comment: You missed some `voids` in your update where you return `this`.

Comment: I think you just gotta `(int)e` my friend. Don't go crazy for such a small thing, there are better things to code!

Comment: I could live with the setter, but three line getter is kind of driving me nuts. Especially if you need to do this for multiple enums, like in my case for 5 different enums. I don't essentially want 5 helper variables and 5 additional casts for what actually is 5 ints.

Comment: Try creating another Get and SetTo method using new constraints as per one of the solutions defined here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/79126/create-generic-method-constraining-t-to-an-enum

Comment: @Don Thanks, that question was already linked, but I cannot create a second overload with a different type constraint and I need the other method since it works well for all the other objects.

Comment: You could make an overload that accepts `MyEnum` and does the dirty conversions for you... But really, you wouldn't even want *two* variables for a single field with a setter and getter, in any real scenario. If you're fighting the language - your design doesn't suit it.

Comment: Silly me, didn't see that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments to my question and Gian Paolo's answer, it has become clear that - opposed to VB.NET - C# does not support implicit type conversion of `enum` to `int` or vice versa, even when using tricks.

Hence, my desired "one-method handles all enum types" solution is impossible to achieve.

If you cannot (project hierarchy) or do not want to add overloads per enum type to the `Writer`/`Reader` class itself, you can create extension methods for the enum types.

Answer (score 1):

Little late on the answer but since I was having the same issue, an overload like this should work

```
public void Foo(int a)
{
    // do something
}

public void Foo(Enum @enum)
{
    Foo(Convert.ToInt32(@enum));
}
```

Comment: This looks very promising, I'll try it out. For the most generic setup, I should probably expand the writer for byte and long, and then check for the right conversion method using Enum.GetUnderlyingType.

Answer (score 0):

with the where constraint:

```
public void Get<T>(out T value) where T : class, IInterface, new()
```

you are explicitly saying that T has to be a reference type (not a value type, as enums are). Try to delete class constraint.

[edit]
you can also try this, avoiding out param:

```
  public T Get<T>() where T : new()
  {
    return default(T);
  }
```

and call it as

```
c.Get<MyEnum>();
```

but again, if you add an IInterface constraint, no Enum can satisfy it.

Comment: I need that constraint, since I want an overload for objects implementing that interface, and I need that interface in the `Get` method.

Comment: No, I don't want it to resolve to `Get<T>(T value)` at all. It should instead resolve to `Get(int)` since the enum type is an int.

Comment: @LWChris, enums aren't ints in C#. You need to switch your idiom view here and work with the language; not fight it.

Comment: @DavidArno Since VB.NET language treated both equally, I assumed C#.NET would, too. If that's not the case, that's fine, but as C# rookie you can't tell whether it's you doing it wrong or the language being utterly different if your usual code pattern does not compile against a different but closely related programming language.