# c# "Enum" on method and "enum" parameter

Tags: c#, enums

This is a difficult question to google!

I have an extension method that takes "Enum" as a parameter.

```
    public static T GetEntry<T>(this Dictionary<Enum, string> dictionary, Enum key)
    {
        string val;
        if (dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out val))
        {
            return (T)Convert.ChangeType(val, typeof(T));               
        }
        return default(T);
    }
```

but when I try to use it with a declared enum the compiler can't find the extension method

```
Dictionary<CmdAttr, String> Attributes;
cmd.CommandText.Attributes.GetEntry<double>(CommandText.CmdAttr.X);
```

Any idea how to make this work other than to declare the dictionary as

```
Dictionary<Enum, String> Attributes
```

which works but kind of defeats the point in having a declared enum?

Many Thanks

Comment: A `Dictionary<CmdAttr, String>` does not inherit from `Dictionary<Enum, string>`, and is thus not compatible. You will have to use a generic type for that parameter but since it isn't allowed in C# to make a generic constraint on enums it would potentially accept any type here.

Comment: Side note: Why are you checking twice if the key exists?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen you can make a constraint on `struct` though. Could help a bit.

Comment: Removed 2 of the 3 dictionary lookups (you only need one).

Comment: try `public static T GetEntry<T, K>(this Dictionary<K, string> dictionary, K key)`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/79126/create-generic-method-constraining-t-to-an-enum

Comment: Thanks Anders, that was cut and paste stupidity ;)

Comment: Thanks Zohar, that works great, I assumed enum would be detected as Enum

Comment: You should also take CodeCaster's link into consideration.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it exactly like you want to, because individual enums are not subclasses of `Enum`. But although this code isn't as pretty as you'd like, it's hardly ugly, and it works as you'd like:

```
// MyTestEnum.cs

enum MyTestEnum
{
    First,
    Second,
    Third
}

// Extensions.cs

static class Extensions
{
    public static TResult GetEntry<TEnum, TResult>(this Dictionary<TEnum, string> dictionary, TEnum key)
    {
        string value;
        if (dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out value))
        {
            return (TResult)Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(TResult));
        }
        return default(TResult);
    }
}

// most likely Program.cs

void Main()
{
    Dictionary<MyTestEnum, string> attributes = new Dictionary<MyTestEnum, string>();
    attributes.Add(MyTestEnum.First, "1.23");

    // *** here's the actual call to the extension method ***
    var result = attributes.GetEntry<MyTestEnum, double>(MyTestEnum.First);

    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

What you would like to do is (the following is not valid C# code):

```
public static T GetEntry<T,U>(this Dictionary<U, string> dictionary, U key) where U : Enum
{
    // your code
}
```

This will not compile (Constraint cannot be special class 'Enum'). 
So you have to look for alternatives. There are some good answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79126/create-generic-method-constraining-t-to-an-enum) question. The most easy way would be to use `where U : struct, IConvertible`

Comment: this is basically taking CodeCaster's and my comment and combining them to an answer. However, your answer could be and should be more complete.

Comment: @ZoharPeled You are welcome to suggest how to make my answer more complete.