# Unity Editor EditorGUILayout.EnumPopup with generics

Tags: generics, unity-game-engine, editor

Hi I have a small problem with a funccion. I need some help

```
public static void BuildContentEnum<T>(string label, string toolTip, SerializedProperty property) 
{
    EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal();

    property.enumValueIndex = (T)EditorGUILayout.EnumPopup(BuildContentBasic(label, toolTip), (T)Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)).GetValue(property.enumValueIndex));

    EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal();
}
```

> error CS1503: Argument `#2' cannot convert`T' expression to type `System.Enum'

Comment: `EditorGUILayout.EnumPopup` returns `Enum` so can not use it with a generic/template `T`, I guess. use something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/79126/create-generic-method-constraining-t-to-an-enum

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a closing parenthesis.

```
 (T) EditorGUILayout.EnumPopup(
          BuildContentBasic(label, toolTip), 
          (T)Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)) // here should be an extra parenthesis
          .GetValue(property.enumValueIndex)); // Here you should remove one
```

At least this is how I understand it, enumValueIndex is an integer but EnumPopup returns and enum, that won't do. So you want to get the value of the enum.

But I would think there is an easier way:

```
int value = property.enumValueIndex;
```