# C# : Is there a way to pass an enum as an argument?

Tags: c#, enums, parameter-passing, checkedlistbox

I've searched (maybe not enough) but couldn't find an answer.

I want to make a generic function where I can pass any enum to use with a `CheckedListBox` (get or set the value).

```
public enum TypeFlags
{
    None = 0x0,
    //List of flag
}

private void makeFlagOrBitmask(CheckedListBox list, Type e)
{
    int myFlags = 0x0;

    //I want to achieve something like that
    foreach (Object item in list.CheckedItems)
    {
        //(TypeFlags)Enum.Parse(typeof(TypeFlags), item);
        //So e should be the enum himself, but i can't figure how to do that
        myFlags += (int)((e)Enum.Parse(typeof(e), item.tostring()));
    }
}
```

So, I can make/read any flags with a single function.

The problem is that I can't figure out how to pass the enum as I need it in the function.

Comment: Remove typeof(e) and leave Enum.Parse(e...  As e is already a type?

Comment: `typeof(e)` when `e` is `Type` is just going to give you type object for `Type`, not the enum type.  You want to just pass `e` to `Enum.Parse`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create Generic method constraining T to an Enum](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/79126/create-generic-method-constraining-t-to-an-enum)

Comment: Yep, i want to rush everything as always and i don't think enough. Thanks guys =)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You want to change this line:

```
myFlags += (int)((e)Enum.Parse(typeof(e), item.tostring()));
```

Into this:

```
myFlags += (int)((e)Enum.Parse(e, item.tostring()));
```

Since `e` is already a type. As of how to pass the parameter:

```
makeFlagOrBitmask(myCheckBoxList, typeof(myEnum));
```

I hope this helps.

**EDIT:**

To make sure only enums will work, add this to the top of your function:

```
if (!e.IsEnum)
    return;
```

Comment: This allows you to pass types that aren't enums.

Comment: That's what i needed as i said above. Thanks !

Comment: @SiveurWesttunger Great, I made an edit, so check that out. Also, could you accept my answer? That'd be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

might not be complete but it sounds like you need a generic Enum iterator. I picked up the below code from [Create Generic method constraining T to an Enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79126/create-generic-method-constraining-t-to-an-enum)

```
public T GetEnumFromString<T>(string value) where T : struct, IConvertible
{
   if (!typeof(T).IsEnum) 
   {
      throw new ArgumentException("T must be an enumerated type");
   }

   //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not a nice Code but this works for me:

If the method want an object instead of a type (maybe you can do this with a type) you can do it like this:

```
if (e.GetType() == typeof(ImageType))
    {
        ValueArray = GetEnumArray(ImageType.Bmg);
    }
```

This way you can check what Enum it es before you do something.

I hope this can help you.