# Cast generic but known to be enum nullable type to nullable int

Tags: c#, generics, enums

I know this may sound a bit weird, but I want to cast an object of `T?` to `int?`. The reason why I want this is that `T` is always an enum and I also know this enum will be castable to int. I'm creating a generic wrapper class for enums and found [this "solution"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/79903/3326982) to constrain the generic type to be an enum type.

My code currently looks like this:

```
public class EnumWrapper<T>
    where T : struct, IConvertible
{
    public EnumWrapper()
    {
        if (!typeof(T).IsEnum)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("T must be an enumerated type");
        }
    }

    public T? Enum { get; set; }

    public int? EnumValue => (int?)Enum;    // this won't compile

    ...
}
```

I know that casting to object before casting to a value type (`(int?)(object)Enum`) tricks the compiler, but does this work here too? I suspect the nullable interferes with this.

So my question is: What is the best way to implement this generic behavior?

Comment: Perhaps `new Nullable<int>((int)(this.Enum as object))`?

Comment: yeah this compiles, but does this work correctly with the nullable? Generally, there should be no difference to `(int?)(object)Enum`, or am I wrong?

Comment: It does seem to work correct with `Nullable` too

Comment: Ok, I'll try this out. Still, it doesn't seem to me like the best solution...

Comment: A more elegant solution using C# 6: `public int? EnumValue => this.Enum?.ToInt32(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat);`

Comment: This certainly looks nicer!

Comment: Just because it's an enum, that doesn't guarantee that it can be cast to an `int`. Notably, enums can be based on `uint`s or `long`/`ulong`.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever yeah you are right, but in my case this isn't going to happen - I even use Int16 (short) in the real code because it will never be that high

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, True. But since the OP already exposes the `EnumValue` property as `int?`, it will be fine in this case. Otherwise, there is no reason for the wrapper anyway.

Comment: The other day I posted a message on CodeProject titled "Fun with Generic Enum Constraint" (see www.codeproject.com/Feature/WeirdAndWonderful.aspx?msg=5071953 ). Well, you were struck by those problems, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `T` is `IConvertible`, you can avoid casting and boxing using the `ToInt32()` method:

```
public int? EnumValue => this.Enum?.ToInt32(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat);
```

And `this.Enum?` will make sure to return `null` in case the actual value is missing.

Also, since we're trying to retain the value-type semantics of the wrapped Enum, you'll want to change `EnumWrapper` from `class` to `struct` and use an extension method to easily wrap the value:

```
public struct EnumWrapper<T> where T : struct, IConvertible
{
    public T? Enum { get; set; }
    public int? EnumValue => this.Enum?.ToInt32(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat);
}

public static class EnumWrapperExtension
{
    public static EnumWrapper<T> Wrap<T>(this T data) where T : struct, IConvertible
    {
        if (!typeof(T).IsEnum)
            throw new ArgumentException("T must be an enumerated type");

        return new EnumWrapper<T> { Enum = data };
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
public enum Color
{
    Red = 1,
    Green = 2,
}

var color = Color.Green;
var colorAsInt = color.Wrap().EnumValue;
```

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iconvertible.toint32(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: best part of this is that you can be sure the nullable is correctly handled - thanks!

Comment: I'd love to give another +1 for the suggestion with the extension method - thanks, I think I'm going to use this

Comment: The only drawback is that I can't use the constructor to check if `T` really is an enum

Comment: @FlorianKoch, I moved that check to the extension method.