# How to pass generic type down to static method

Tags: c#

I have a generic method which will return a select list populated from an enum.

```
public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetGenericEnumSelectList<T>()
{
     return (Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)).Cast<int>().Select(e => new SelectListItem() { Text = EnumExtensions.GetEnumDescription((ProductsEnum)e) , Value = e.ToString() })).ToList();
}
```

I have put a call to a static method I also have called `GetEnumDescription`, this expects an Enum. How can I pass in the current type rather than hard coding the type as I have done. So that if `T` is a different type of enum, it will be generic.

Something like:

```
public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetGenericEnumSelectList<T>()
{
    return (Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)).Cast<int>().Select(e => new SelectListItem() { Text = EnumExtensions.GetEnumDescription((typeof(T))e) , Value = e.ToString() })).ToList();
}
```

**EDIT**

Signature of `GetEnumDescription` is

```
public static string GetEnumDescription(Enum value)
{

///

}
```

Comment: What is the signature of `GetEnumDescription`? I bet it´ll contain `Enum` as first parameter, not the *actual* type of enum. So there´s no need to cast to the specific type at all.

Comment: you can cast using generic type as any other type  `(T)e`

Comment: @Rafal That assumes there´s a generic constraint for enum, [which it is not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79126/create-generic-method-constraining-t-to-an-enum).

Comment: e is an int at that point, I get "Argument type 'T' is not assignable to parameter type 'System.Enum'

Comment: Useful in C#7.3: [Enum constraint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters#enum-constraints)

Comment: Why not simply cast to `Enum` if your signature needs `Enum` anyway?

Comment: "Argument type `T` is not assignable to parameter type `System.Enum`" Because `T` can be *everything*, not just an enum. Unfortunately there´s no generic constraint for enum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately there´s no generic constraint for enums - at least not before [C#7.3](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters#enum-constraints). So the following isn´t possible:

```
void SoSomething<T>(T myEnum) where T: Enum { }
```

You could add another constraint as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79126/create-generic-method-constraining-t-to-an-enum):

```
void SoSomething<T>(T myEnum) where T: struct, IConvertible{ }
```

However that won´t help you much.

However in your case there´s no need to cast at all, as your methods parameter is `Enum`. So you can simply cast `e` to `Enum`:

```
return (Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)).Cast<Enum>().Select(e => new SelectListItem { 
    Text = EnumExtensions.GetEnumDescription(e), 
    Value = Convert.ToInt32(e).ToString() 
})).ToList();
```

Bw aware on the cast to `Enum`. Otherwise you get the following error:

> Cannot convert type `int` to `System.Enum`

Comment: Cannot convert type 'int' to 'System'Enum'

Comment: @JsonStatham Cast to `object` before as seen in my update.

Comment: This works in terms of the Text now, however the value is no longer the integer but a copy of the text

Comment: Copy of the text? What? `Enum.GetValues` just returns numbers, no text. And `(Enum)e` won´t neither, so which text you refer to?

Comment: I Mean "Value = e.ToString" used to return the int value of the enum so 0,1 or 2. Now it returns the enum text "Red, Yellow, Green"