# Combine flags of generic Enum

Tags: c#, generics, enums, enum-flags

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8086788/5755482) answer we can have generics constrained to System.Enum since C# 7.3.

However, while one can check any flag of an unkown Enum with

> HasFlag(Enum flag)

it is not possible so set a flag of an unkown Enum, since there is no SetFlag() and the |-operator is not defined for System.Enum.

Basicly what I want to do is the following:

```
public static T Combine<T>(this IEnumerable<T> values) where T : System.Enum
    {
        var value = default(T);

        foreach (var v in values)
        {
            value |= v;
        }

        return value;
    }
```

The C# compiler tells me

> The |=-operator cannot be applied to operands of type 'T' and 'T'.

Is it possible to create such an extension method anyways?

Comment: you could cast them to a `int` or `long` then back.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to [Daniel A. White](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23528/daniel-a-white)'s comment I could solve it now like this:

```
    public static T CombineIntEnums<T>(this IEnumerable<T> values) where T : Enum
    {
        int? result = null;

        foreach (var enumVal in values)
        {
            // convert enum to int
            var intVal = Convert.ToInt32(enumVal);

            if (result.HasValue == false)
                result = intVal;

            result |= intVal;
        }

        // convert int to enum
        var val = (T)Enum.ToObject(typeof(T), result ?? 0);

        return val;
    }
```

Comment: @alexei You can't use `(int)enumVal`: 'The type "T" cannot be converted to "int"''

Comment: This will break for any enums not backed by an `int`.  The compiler was *correct* in preventing you from casting it.  Just turning it into a runtime error is just obscuring the bug.

Comment: @Servy if you write this as the answer I'll gladly accept it but for the moment this extension method comes in handy for me

Comment: Seems to work with everything except Long/ULong (OverflowException) changing it to `ToInt64()` should be fine (unless you're using a lot, then you might have to use BigInteger).