# Create Generic Class Accepting T as an enum

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, generics, enums, httpclient

I have this class and i want that to accept a generic as an enum 
I can pas it in the constructor but I want to use generic.

this is my interface:

```
public interface ITrnApi<TEnum> : IDisposable where TEnum : struct
```

and I want my class to be like this one

```
public class TrnApi<TEnum> : ITrnApi<TEnum> where TEnum : struct
{
    private readonly HttpClient _http;

    public TrnApi(HttpClient http, TEnum company)
    {
        _http = http;
        _http.BaseAddress = company.ToBaseUrl().ToUri();

        //public enum Company
        //{
        //    test = 1,
        //    othertest = 2
        //}
    }
}
```

but get this error:

> 'TEnum' does not contain a definition for 'ToBaseUrl' and the best
>   extension method overload 'Extentions.ToBaseUrl(Company, string)'
>   requires a receiver of type 'Company'

How can I do that?

Comment: If you are looking for a generic `enum` constraint, see [Create Generic method constraining T to an Enum](https://stackoverflow.com/q/79126/3744182).  But it appears that `Extentions.ToBaseUrl()` is an extension method on a *specific type* of enum, specifically `Company`, so using a generic here isn't sensible.

Comment: @dbc  you mean it cant be done?

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do.  Why are you making the class generic when only one specific `enum` type is actually allowed?  Is the `enum` saved somewhere in the class, even though it isn't shown?  Can you edit your question to share a [mcve]?

Comment: @dbc the thing I trying to do you said it in your first comment  so you suggest I should use the constructor for that

Comment: @alirezas Please, share with us `ToBaseUrl()` method, how it's declared

Answer (score 2):

The `System.Enum` constraint is available starting from C# 7.3.

```
public class TrnApi<TEnum> : ITrnApi<TEnum> where TEnum : struct, Enum
{
    private readonly HttpClient _http;

    public TrnApi(HttpClient http, TEnum company)
    {
        _http = http;
        _http.BaseAddress = company.ToBaseUrl().ToUri();
        /* ... */
    }
}
```