# Why do you use "where T: struct" for generic enum extension methods in C#?

Tags: c#

I've seen examples of generic extension methods in C# for enumerations that use `where T: struct`, also another that uses `where T: IComparable`. For example, in the former case:

```cs
public static class EnumExtensionMethods
{
  public static string Description<T>(this T enumValue) where T : struct
  {
    // ...
  }
}
```

I'm confused why the constraint requires that type `T` must be a `struct`. I'd expect it to be `where T : Enum`. Can someone explain this to me? As a bonus item, maybe also explain why `IComparable` is also used in some examples.

FWIW, I did my research on this. I can find explanations on why `IComparable` is used, for example [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79126/create-generic-method-constraining-t-to-an-enum), but it doesn't seem conclusive, nor do they explain why `struct` is used in conjunction.

Comment: The `Enum` generic constraint wasn't added until C# 7.3, so I'd expect generic methods written before that feature to use `struct`

Comment: Note: "As a bonus item, maybe also explain why IComparable is also used in some examples." Stack Overflow posts ideally deal with just a single question. If still you want an answer to that part, I'd suggest creating another post - and cite some examples, otherwise we're in the dark. (There are plenty of `IComparable` implementations that *aren't* enums, for example.)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I suspect you're looking at some code that was written before C# 7.3 - the ability to constrain a generic type parameter using `Enum` or `Delegate` was only introduced in C# 7.3.

But for extension methods targeting enums, you'd want *both* `Enum` and `struct` in the constraint, e.g.

```cs
public static string GetDescription<T>(this T enumValue) where T : struct, Enum
{
    // ...
}
```

That way it can only be called on *concrete* enum types, rather than `GetDescription<Enum>(null)`.

Comment: Thanks, this helps, but what I'm really looking for is to understand semantically why an enum is related to a `struct`. I come from C++ primarily so maybe it's something idiomatic to C# I am missing. Can you explain this at the type level? Why does `T` have to be a `struct`? EDIT: Maybe the answer lies in your last sentence, but I don't understand it yet.

Comment: @void.pointer: Sorry, I assume you already understood enums at a C# level, separately from generics. Enums are always value types (although the System.Enum type is not). The `struct` constraint ensures that the type argument is a value type; the combined `where T : struct, Enum` constraint ensures that it's "a value type derived from System.Enum" - basically "that it's a specific enum type".

Comment: Thanks @JonSkeet, that helps a ton.

Answer (score 2):

The ability to constrain a method to `Enum` is relatively new in C#. Using `struct` was a way to at least not allow reference types to be used.