# Enum.TryParse not accepted in generic restricted to Enum

Tags: c#, generics, enums

I think I'm probably doing something silly but I'm trying to write a generic function that takes a `string` and converts it into an `enum` (and then does some other stuff that I've skipped for sake of brevity).
The problem is, it complains that `Enum.TryParse` needs a type that isn't nullable, it complains that T is nullable; Seemingly `System.Enum` is nullable but actual enums aren't nullable.
Is there something I'm doing wrong here or is there a way around the problem.

```
private T GetEnumFilter<T>(string strValue) where T : Enum
{
     return Enum.TryParse(strValue, out T value) ? value : throw new Exception("Invalid value");
}
```

I've seen this https://stackoverflow.com/a/8086788/1093406 answer and the sample at [the dotnet samples](https://github.com/dotnet/samples/blob/3ee82879284e3f4755251fd33c3b3e533f7b3485/snippets/csharp/keywords/GenericWhereConstraints.cs#L180-L190) and can't see what I've done wrong.

Comment: You shouldn't shadow your argument name with a variable name. Use some different name for `out T value` and `? value :`

Comment: @ckuri: there's already answer suggesting that

Comment: Sorry, made a couple of errors when simplifying my code for SO. Thanks to @HereticMonkey for pointing out the mistake

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Seemingly System.Enum is nullable but actual enums aren't nullable.

Yes, just like `System.ValueType` is a reference type, but value types themselves aren't.

You just need to add a `struct` constraint:

```cs
private T GetEnumFilter<T>(string value) where T : struct, Enum
```

This compiles, for example:

```cs
private static T GetEnumFilter<T>(string value) where T : struct, Enum =>
    Enum.TryParse(value, out T result) ? result : throw new Exception("Invalid value");
```

Comment: Thanks @Jon for the amazingly fast answer. I've fixed the code errors in my question introduced when simplifying for SO but the super simple addition of struct is what I was missing.