# How to write a generic function for enum types

Tags: c#

```
 //TechTeam is enum type
 //This line returns the enumvalue as out param, for the matching stringvalue.

 Enum.TryParse(stringvalue, out TechTeam tt);
```

It works perfectly. Now if I turn it to generic I am using

```
private T enumparse<T>(string state)
    {
        Enum.TryParse<T>(state, out T stateout);
        return stateout;
    }
```

it throws error.

I changed the code to :

```
 private T? enumparse<T>(string? state) where T: System.Enum
    {
        Enum.TryParse<T>(state, out T stateout);
        return stateout;
    }
```

It says the Type T must be a non nullable value.

Comment: The accepted answer is incomplete, though, as it could allow `System.Enum` itself. You also need the `struct` constraint to prevent `System.Enum` from being allowed. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28527552) is the one that's complete and correct.

Comment: "it throws error" is never sufficient information in a Stack Overflow question. Always *always* provide the details of the error.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try setting a type constraint? I'm pretty sure there is a variation that can work with `Enum`.

```
private T enumparse<T>(string state) where T : struct, Enum
{
    Enum.TryParse<T>(state, out T stateout);
    return stateout;
}
```