# Property to index an array by an enum in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, properties, enums, indexing

I realize that I can select an element from an array from an enum by casting it as an int, but since I need to do that numerous times in my code, I was wondering if there is a way to set up a property or something like that to reduce code duplication. How would I be able to do something like this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Indexing arrays with enums in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/443935/indexing-arrays-with-enums-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

Casting an `enum` to an `int` extremely efficient. In fact, in most cases, the compiler does most of the work for you already. For example, using a constant like this `arr[(int)MyEnum.Value]` will be automatically compiled into an int literal like `arr[7]`. 
 So there's really no need to try to speed this up.

However, if your `enum` values do not strictly range from 0 — *n*, (where *n* < `array.length`), then suggest using a `Dictionary` instead.

Comment: My point wasn't to make it faster. I want to reduce code duplication of casting. Also, I could do a check once for invalid enums if it was separate in a property.