# Using integer enum as a index for arrays in C# without converting?

Tags: c#, enums

I have a large collection of data, i need to store the same in string array.

this array then passed into another class as callback event.

so i need to use index as enum values so that outside person can read the string values easily.

for this i tried this,

```
public enum PublicData : int 
{
  CardNo = 0,
  CardName = 1,
  Address = 2,
   //etc....
}
```

then i have accessed this by,

```
string[] Publicdata = new string[iLength];
Publicdata[PublicData.CardNo] =  cardNovalue;
```

but here i am getting "invalid type for index - error"

How to resolve the same.

Comment: There's a discussion about this here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/443935/indexing-arrays-with-enums-in-c-sharp

Comment: Sounds to me like those should not be enum members at all, but properties of a data class.

Answer (score 3):

Create custom collection class and add indexer property with PublicData enum as indexer.

```
public enum PublicData : int
{
    CardNo = 0,
    CardName = 1,
    Address = 2,
}

public class PublicdataCollection
{
    private readonly string[] _inner;

    public string this[PublicData index]
    {
        get { return _inner[(int)index]; }
        set { _inner[(int) index] = value; }
    }

    public PublicdataCollection(int count)
    {
        _inner = new string[count];
    }
}
```

Comment: Looked for an easy or inbuilt c# answer for this. but this seems to converting to int inside the class, and i don't know about the performance if i called this inside the thread routine.  finally just converting to int better than this since i need code performance.  thanks for pinging.

Answer (score 2):

Just cast your enum value

```
Publicdata[(int)PublicData.CardNo] =  cardNovalue;
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can go with an Extension method:

```
public static class MyEnumExtensions
{
    public static int Val(this PublicData en)
    {
        return (int)en;            
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Publicdata[PublicData.Address.Val()];
```

Comment: @ bati,  Dear , i know this,  but  As i mentioned in my question title                 i need answer  without converting to int.

Comment: Why not just **return (int)en;**