# Generic class, operator overload for differing types

Tags: c#

So, I'm moving from C++ to C# ( well, not 'moving', but visiting ) and I'm trying to port over a C++ project I have as practice.  I can't seem to find anything that references my particular problem.  I have a template class Rect -

```
template< class T >
class Rect
{
public:
    Rect() {}
    Rect( T top, T bottom, T left, T right )
    :
    top( top ),
    bottom( bottom ),
    left( left ),
    right( right )
    {}
    Rect( const Rect& rect )
    :
    top( rect.top ),
    bottom( rect.bottom ),
    left( rect.left ),
    right( rect.right )
    {}
    void Translate( float dx, float dy )
    {
        top += (T)dy;
        bottom += (T)dy;
        left += (T)dx;
        right += (T)dx;
    }
    template< class T2 >
    operator Rect< T2 >() const
    {
        return Rect< int >( (T2) top, (T2)bottom, (T2)left, (T2)right );
    }
    void ClipTo( const Rect& rect )
    {
        top = max( top, rect.top );
        bottom = min( bottom, rect.bottom );
        left = max( left, rect.left );
        right = min( right, rect.right );
    }
public:
    T top;
    T bottom;
    T left;
    T right;
};
```

The problem is the Translate( float dx, float dy ) method.  It seems I can't add a float to a 'T' or even use 'T' to type another variable?  Overloading the '+' operator doesn't seem to be the answer ( same problem - type mismatch ).  Am I missing something painfully simple?

Comment: No, you're not. Unfortunately, in C# you can not do arithmetic operations with generic typed arguments; there is no way in the language to constraint T to an "addable", "multipliable", etc. type. This is currently, IMHO, a shortcoming of the type system.

Comment: expecting T to be a numeric type breaks using generics.

Comment: @RadioSpace No it does not. Why would it? Following that logic, any constraint "breaks" generics. Why would `where T: IFoo` be any different? As a matter of fact the CLR team has considered solving this issue more than once: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6695760/767890

Comment: @InBetween okay maybe "Breaks" was a little strong

Answer (score 0):

okay..

the actual implementation in my example below is very redundant. but I am merely showing how Extension methods may be able to solve this (even if only partially)

```
using System;


namespace FOOBAR
{
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Foo<string> stringFoo = new Foo<string>("this");
        stringFoo.Value = "that";

        Foo<float> floatFoo = new Foo<float>(2f);
        floatFoo.SetFloat(4f);//same as  

    }

}

class Foo<T>
{ 
    T value;
    public T Value { get { return value; } set { this.value = value; } }

    public Foo(T val)
    {
        value = val;
    }
}

public static class FooHelper //this is a class we don't use by itself
{

    //this is an extension method we can use directly from the extended type (Foo<Float>)
    public static void SetFloat(this Foo<float> floatFoo, float value)
    {
        floatFoo.Value = value;//this is redunant unless we do something more complicated
    }
}
}
```

and in visual studio you will see

[image]

and for non float foos:

[image]

this specific use is very redundant. but maybe this will give you some direction.

and be careful I visited c# for XNA many years ago and haven't got back into C++ since.

Comment: Okay, so I can overload the helper method to have one for Rect<float> and another for Rect<int> ( I really only need those two ), right?  And I know what you mean, @RadioSpace, about going back to C++ - once I get my head around some of these minor annoyances, I think I might hang around in C# for a while.

Comment: @JoeKnowles yep, make one for each generic. a little tedious. but you are a  programmer after all

Comment: Ugh!  I thought I had it, but I still ran into 'type' problems.  Ended up just making it class RectF and I'll just use floats everywhere (bfd).

Comment: I get the logic behind not implementing 'type switch'ing and such, but a simple bit of explicit casting wouldn't go amiss.  I mean, if you can't say "myInt = myFloat;" you should at least be able to say, "myInt = (int)myFloat;"  But, whatever.  I guess I can cross my fingers for 6.0, right?

Answer (score 0):

C# won't allow you to use arithmetic when using generics. One way to get around this is to use compiled expressions. For example, here's generic adder:

```
public static class Calculator<T>
{
    private static readonly Func<T, T, T> add;

    static Calculator() 
    {
        var param1 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
        var param2 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
        var addLambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, T, T>>(
            Expression.Add(param1, param2),
            param1, param2
        );
        add = addLambda.Compile();
    }

    // invoke as Calculator<T>.Add(a, b)
    public static T Add(T a, T b)
    {   
        return add(a, b);
    }
}
```

This solution is a bit clunky, but you only have to write the calculator class once. You can use similar code to create other arithmetic and mathematical operators for generic types. For the example you posted, you'd also need a way to convert from `float` to T (or just change Translate() to take in T's). To do the convert, you could add the following to Calculator:

```
private static readonly Func<float, T> fromFloat;

...


// in the static constructor
var floatParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(float));
var fromFloatLambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<float, T>>(
    Expression.Convert(floatParameter, typeof(T)),
    floatParameter
);
fromFloat = fromFloatLambda.Compile();


// add a new method
public static T FromFloat(T t) { return fromFloat(t); }
```

Comment: Huh.  I'll have to go back and try this...And at the same time, wonder why I haven't seen this solution ( or similar ) in 4 hrs of Binging!  I love lambdas and I wasn't familiar with the expression tree stuff.  Neat.  Thanks.

Comment: @JoeKnowles: I'm not sure why there isn't much information on this, but there is a bit out there. For example, I just found [this question](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/26022/generic-calculator-and-generic-number) and [this library](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/miscutil/usage/genericoperators.html) (referenced by a comment to the previous). Unfortunately, you kind of have to know the answer in order to find it.