# Implicit conversion for generic class restricted only to some types

Tags: c#, .net, generics, implicit-conversion

Assume we have idea for generic class `Matrix<T>` where `T` is numeric type (`Complex` or `double` or `float`, `int` etc).

It is natural that we have implicit conversions in C# from `float` to `double`, from `double` to `Complex`. General rule is that we have implicit conversion from smaller type to bigger type. So far so good.

Now imagine we are implementing our `Matrix<T>` type. Since this new type in a way is numeric also (or at least it holds numeric values) it is only natural to have implicit conversions from `Matrix<float>` to `Matrix<double>`, from `Matrix<double>` to `Matrix<Complex>` etc. At least it is nice to have these for mathematical operations like multiply, add etc. However this seems impossible to implement correctly because implicit operator requires that at least one type is the same as class we are implementing it in.

Example: below code doesn't compile even thought it could resolve my problem.

```
public abstract partial class Matrix<T>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Implicitly converts a matrix to double precision complex numbers.
    /// </summary>
    public static implicit operator Matrix<Complex64>(Matrix<double> matrix)
    {
        matrix.ToComplex();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Implicitly converts a matrix to double precision real numbers.
    /// </summary>
    public static implicit operator Matrix<double>(Matrix<float> matrix)
    {
        matrix.ToDouble();
    }
}
```

It will not compile because "CS0556 User-defined conversion must convert to or from the enclosing type" and let's say I'm fine with that because it is part of the language specification but shouldn't there be any other way to achieve this?

For example this doesn't compile either.

```
public abstract partial class Matrix<double>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Implicitly converts a matrix to single precision real numbers.
    /// </summary>
    public static implicit operator Matrix<double>(Matrix<float> matrix)
    {
        matrix.ToDouble();
    }
}
```

Is there any way to achieve this thing, it feels natural so I think it should be achievable?

For now I have created a workaround which enables implicit conversion for all types to biggest one but that doesn't resolve conversion from `Matrix<float>` to `Matrix<double>`, it only resolves conversions to `Matrix<Complex>`.

```
public abstract partial class Matrix<T>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Implicitly converts a matrix to double precision complex numbers.
    /// </summary>
    public static implicit operator Matrix<Complex64>(Matrix<T> matrix)
    {
        return matrix.Map(x =>
        {
            if (x is Numerics.Complex32)
            {
                var xc32 = (Numerics.Complex32)(object)x;
                return new Complex64(xc32.Real, xc32.Imaginary);
            }
            return new Complex64(Convert.ToDouble(x), 0);
        }, Zeros.AllowSkip);
    }
}
```

If anyone is interested in background around this problem, you may take a look at  https://github.com/mathnet/mathnet-numerics/issues/304

Another option to resolve this could be to use something like "extension operators" (similar to extension methods) but those are not present in C#.

Comment: Honestly as a user of such an API I'd fear an implicit cast like that. What about explicit casts? Would that work for you?

Comment: @OndrejTucny No, unfortunately I think implicit cast is the only way to go.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I'm not really sure using generics with numeric primitive types is a good path to go down. This is a pretty serious lacking aspect of the language and there doesn't seem to be any plan in addressing it on short notice. Read [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6695760/767890) for more info.

1. There is no numeric constraint, the best you can do is `struct` which is pretty bad.
2. For any arithmetic support, which is a must if you are implementing a matrix, you need to define an `IArithmetic` interface with `Add`, `Multiply` etc., and you'll be boxing and unboxing all over the place which can be a big performance impact.

   Your code is far worse than that; because you seem to be lacking a common interface for `T` you need to cast to object to make the generic cast succeed.

   Also if you don't have a common interface code similar to `if (typeof(T) == typeof(Complex)) ...` starts to appear, which is a big red flag when using generics; a generic class / method should work on an *infinite* number of types, not just a few preset types, that is what *generic* means.

I think you should take a step back and rethink your approach. When the language type system seems to be fighting against you and not helping in any way, its a sure sign you are doing something wrong.

Why don't you simply implement a non generic matrix of the largest type? A matrix of complex numbers. What is the benefit of having a matrix of floats or doubles? It can't be performance or memory efficiency because any non generic solution will be better than your current approach with all the boxing an unboxing going on.

*UPDATE*: After looking through the library you are basing this on, I'm not sure why you are not using `Matrix<T>` as intended in the first place: as a base type.

```
public class DoubleMatrix : Matrix<double>
{
    //now this is legal
    public static implicit operator DoubleMatrix(FloatMatrix matrix)
        => matrix.ToDouble();
}
```

Where `FloatMatrix` is obviously `FloatMatrix: Matrix<Float>`.

Comment: Well first of all I am not implementing this from scratch. This is fork of MathNet.Numerics library (I have linked to the issue I am trying to resolve). Honestly the library has quite good code but I really need this implicit conversion to work.

AFAIK they allow floats etc for performance reason (working with native providers such as Intel MKL).

Comment: @PawelTroka Well, first of all, that is relevant information you should put up front in your question. Second, the code in your cast is still yours, and the cast to `object` just to make your code compile is horrendous from a performance point of view.

Comment: it's hard to decide what is more important sometimes. In terms of performance I guess option 2 from my proposal of implementation  should be faster but the code is uglier (https://github.com/mathnet/mathnet-numerics/issues/304)

Comment: regarding an updated answer - yes this will work but only if we are using types that inherit from Matrix<T>. Compiler will still not compile code below (because there is no implicit operator for Matrix<T> that converts it to Matrix<double>):
            var floatMatrix = Matrix<float>.Build.Dense(Size, Size);
            var doubleMatrix = Matrix<double>.Build.Dense(Size, Size);

            var result = floatMatrix*doubleMatrix;
CS0019 Operator '*' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Matrix<float>' and 'Matrix<double>'

It is also "conversion from base class"

Comment: Ok, I have checked to be sure and it will not work because it is compiler error "conversion from base class".

Comment: @PawelTroka woops! true, missed that, sorry. You can't use the generic form in the operator, you need to use other concrete implementations. Edited answer. There is no way around this but its also the best solution, `Matrix<T>` is not meant to be used the way you are thinking in its open form, I think its purpose is to only use it as a base implementation of concrete closed types.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I know to create a generic vector or matrix class and have it do algebra (addition, subtraction, multiplication) is to emit `MSIL` codes that invoke operators (ex. the `operator +`). Then it can be used with *any* type that has `static MyType operator + (MyType a, MyTYpe b)` defined as well as the built in types.

See [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32074803/380384) to a similar question for more details.

Using the static methods from in `Operation<T>` you can have the following example code

```
public class Matrix<T>
{
    T[,] elements;

    static readonly Func<T,T> add = Operation<T>.Add;

    public static Matrix<T> operator + (Matrix<T> A, Matrix<T> B)
    {
       Matrix<T> result = new Matrix<T>(rows,cols);
       for(int i=0; i<rows; i++)
       {
         for(int j=0; j<cols; j++)
         {
            result[i,j] = add(A[i,j], B[i,j]);
         }
       }
       return result;
    }    
    // rest of algebra
}
```

So if you do have a `Complex64` class defined that has `operator +` defined you can declare `Matrix<Complex64>` and do algebra like `var C = A+2*B` directly. The runtime is going to call the appropriate operator for either built in types or custom types. The speed impact is minimal because the reflection to find the appropriate method to call is only done *once* per type at first use.

Comment: Yeah it looks like an interesting approach but notice that I am forking already existing library with most operators already implemented. So the only way for me to implement behavior I need is sadly through implicit conversions.

Comment: Well, nope, that's not the only way. That's the easy way you'd want to exist. But, there are also other ways, just not easy.