# IArithmetic<T> interface in c#

Tags: c#, language-design

I explored c# source code reference. And I came across with interesting mention of `IArithmetic<T>` interface. For example, `Int32`, `Double` contain commented implementations of `IArithmetic` interface. I am interested by these details.  As I understood, it is attempt to add "supporting" of arithmetic operations. But why are they commented? Is it bad way to add supporting generic "operators"?

Comment: OP has a point - here's the commented [`IArithmetic<>`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/int16.cs,4f2f28ae4cd2bc79)

Comment: This is no longer in the coreclr [source](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/mscorlib/src/System/Int32.cs#L26)

Comment: If you're asking us if it's bad or good or useful, it's opinion-based. If you're looking for the authoritative answer on why this was once considered and ultimately not implemented, it's [history-based](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276366/). In either case, it's not a good question for SO.

Comment: @JeroenMostert, thanks I understood. Voting to close question

Comment: Discussion: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/27167

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It was probably scrapped due to performance reasons and not very much usability.

Primitive types supporting arithmetic operations through an interface is really not a very attractive scenario; performance would be horrible compared to simply using the value type itself due to the necessary boxing and unboxing.

What possible uses? Well, the first one to spring to mind would be the following scenario:

```
public Matrix<T> where T: IArithmetic<T>
```

or some such. Although this could be interesting, due to performance reasons, it would probably need to be solved some other way, not through interfaces; read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6695760/767890) for very educated musing on the subject.

On top of all that, if you really need something similar to `Arithmetic<T>` you can always build your own with an added level of indirection.

Comment: You wouldn't need to box in your example.

Comment: @Lee Thats true, isn't it? No idea why this answer was accepted, as a matter of fact I was considering on erasing it becuase I wasn't at all convinced with what I wrote.

Comment: I primarly accepted it as answer because it contains descriptive link.