# How to sum generic numbers in C#?

Tags: c#, generics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# generic constraint for only integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32664/c-sharp-generic-constraint-for-only-integers)

As you can see in the following code, I need to compute the sum of two generic numbers.

```
public class NumberContainer<T>
{
    public T ValueA { get; private set; }
    public T ValueB { get; private set; }
    public T Total { get { return ValueA + ValueB; } }
}
```

However, it isn't possible to do a direct addition of the two T values, which results in the compiler error below :

> Operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'T' and 'T'

Given that I don't intend to use T for anything else than value-types that represent numbers (short, ushort, int, uint, etc), how could I perform the sum? (efficiency is a factor to be considered)

Comment: Or possibly: [Is there a C# generic constraint for “real number” types?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1348594/is-there-a-c-sharp-generic-constraint-for-real-number-types/1348625#1348625)

Comment: The question is closed as a duplicate of questions seeking to put a constraint on `T`, which is *not* what this question is trying to do. I think that it should be reopened.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do it with "little magic" from LINQ:

```
private static readonly Func<T, T, T> adder;
static NumberContainer() {
    var p1 = Expression.Parameter(typeof (T));
    var p2 = Expression.Parameter(typeof (T));
    adder = (Func<T, T, T>)Expression
        .Lambda(Expression.Add(p1, p2), p1, p2)
        .Compile();
} 
public T Total { get { return adder(ValueA, ValueB); } }
```

The only drawback is that this code *will* compile even if `NumberContainer` is instantiated with a type `T` that does not support addition; of course it will throw an exception at run-time. An added benefit is that this *should* work with user-defined `+` operators.

Answer (score 7):

In addition to using LINQ, if you're on .NET 4 this is possible using `dynamic`:

```
static T Add<T>(T x, T y) 
{
    dynamic dx = x, dy = y;
    return dx + dy;
}
```

In your code sample this turns into:

```
public class NumberContainer<T> where T: struct
{
    public T ValueA { get; private set; }
    public T ValueB { get; private set; }
    public T Total { get { return ((dynamic)ValueA) + ((dynamic)ValueB); } }
}
```

This approach doesn't ensure safety though. If `T` is some random struct that doesn't support `+` you'll end up with an exception (I think).

Comment: Scary use of dynamic, especially considering operators are not virtual... I guess it'll "just work" by it's magic box. (I would have preferred structural types *as well* :-/)

Comment: @pst - Agreed, but it does happen to work. I understand the point though.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a constraint for `T` that it must be a struct, and perhaps that it implements IConvertable, and then use `Convert`.

```
public class NumberContainer<T>
        where T : struct, IConvertible
    {
        public T ValueA { get; private set; }
        public T ValueB { get; private set; }
        public T Total {
            get
            {
                // do type checking here, then:

                return (T)Convert.ChangeType(
                    Convert.ToDouble((object)ValueA) +
                    Convert.ToDouble((object)ValueB), typeof(T));
            } 
        }
    }
```

However, there's no way with generics to guarantee that T is an integer or floating type at compile time. You can check it at runtime, though, and throw an exception.

Comment: Did it off the top of my head, fixed and compiles. If you'd like to further elaborate on why it won't work, that'd be a lot more helpful.

Comment: DateTime is a struct and a IConvertible but cannot be converted into double so will just throw an exception anytime you will call it with DateTime parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You could treat this just as an abstract base class and derive specific classes that specified the T value and provided the implementation for Total

```
public abstract class NumberContainer<T>
    where T: struct
{
    public T ValueA { get; private set; }
    public T ValueB { get; private set; }
    public abstract T Total();
}

public class IntContainer : NumberContainer<int>
{
    public override int Total()
    {
        return ValueA + ValueB;
    }
}
```

Comment: If an `int` could be converted to `T` then this wouldn't be a problem. Your code doesn't compile.

Comment: silly me.  Updated answer to provide an alternate solution since there are now a few solutions using dynamics and link