# template struct passed by ref to void function

Tags: c#

I've been trying to get on top of this for some time now and just cant figure this out.

```
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
struct Vec3
{
    T x, y, z;

    Vec3(T _x, T _y, T _z) : x(_x), y(_y), z(_z) {}
};

template <class T>
void IncVec(Vec3<T>& vec)
{
    vec.x += 1;
}

int main(void)
{
    Vec3<float> vec = Vec3<float>(1, 2, 3);
    IncVec(vec);
    std::cout << vec.x;

}
```

I basically want to recreate this in C#. So far I've got this:

```
using System;

namespace cs_playground
{

    public struct Vec3<T>
    {
        public T x, y, z;
        public Vec3(T _x, T _y, T _z)
        {
            x = _x;
            y = _y;
            z = _z;
        }

    }

    class Program
    {

        public static void IncVec(ref Vec3<T> vec)
        {
            vec.x += 1;
        }


        static void Main()
        {
            Vec3<float> vec = new Vec3<float>(1, 2, 3);
            IncVec(ref vec);
            Console.WriteLine(vec.x);
        }
    }
}
```

It really doesnt like the "ref Vec3< T >" .. I mean.. it obviously works with like "ref Vec3< float >" and so on.. but I struggle with like.. passing the type I guess..

Thanks for any kind of help in advance.

Comment: `public static void IncVec<T>(ref Vec3<T> vec)`

Comment: In general, don't try to treat C# and C++ as the same things. Generics aren't Templates. structs and classes mean different things in the two languages, etc.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay i tried that, but it wont let me use + operator for int + struct.. cant I use something, where I could do something  like (ref vec... ) where T : numeric or smth? ..

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever i'll keep that in mind. I just started playing around with c# .. thanks for the info.

Comment: They considered adding an [`IArithmetic`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/int32.cs,249) at one point but it's never happened. So you can't do maths with generic types.

Comment: the problem you face related to Generics in C#. If you try to apply an operator (like +) between two generic types it should be possible to use by any type passed to T within constraints. In this case, as @Damien_The_Unbeliever  mentioned there is no constraint that specifies only arithmetic types. You need some workarounds like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9338398/how-to-sum-generic-numbers-in-c)

Comment: Is there any reason you specifically want a `struct`? Modifying structs is often a bad thing. [They should be immutbale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441309/why-are-mutable-structs-evil). Using a class lets you modify any member directly without the need for `ref`. Alternativly create a new instance of the struct, instead of modifying an existing one.

Comment: There wasnt really any reason to use struct, as I said I was just trying to get to know c# better.. just playing around with it.. (in this case with ref) i wasnt actually aware of it being way more different from class.. anyway, thanks for advice. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem would be the `vec.x += 1` part. The `IncVec` should be able to take any type of `T` and expect it to be able to add 1 to it. But what if `T` is a bool? You cannot add 1 to a bool in C#. Or a random class?

As @Damien_The_Unbeliever pointed out a Template in C++ is **not the same thing** as Generics in C#.

However, in C# you can add constrains to the type `T` like the following (also notice your missing `<T>` after the method name):

```
public static void IncVec<T>(ref Vec3<T> vec)
   where T : xxxx // Constraints to the generic type
{
    vec.x += 1;
}
```

where `xxxx` could for instance be the name of a type or interface (which means that the type `T` must inherit or implement this type). It could also be `class` to say that the type `T` must be a class (and then e.g. `int` will not be allowed) or it could be `struct` to prevent classes to be used.

But there is no constraint you can specify that allow you to use the code `+= 1` that I can think of.

Comment: no possible constraint as C# currently stands since operators are static and so cannot form part of an interface.