# Some specific types in generic function

Tags: c#, generics

I want to make a a function, and i dont want to write it many times with different types.
Can I use 'where' and "tell it" that I want one of the specific types that I write?
By the way, I need a function to handle integers and another to handle floating numbers.

Comment: Sadly there isn't a way to use where to specify numeric types..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a C# generic constraint for "real number" types?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1348594/is-there-a-c-sharp-generic-constraint-for-real-number-types)

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't. There are specific constraints you can apply for type parameters, e.g. it must be a non-nullable value type, or it must be a class, or it must implement an interface or whatever... but you can't specify a set of types and say that it must be one of those.

Even if you *could* do so, I suspect it wouldn't do what you want - because I expect you want to perform arithmetic on these types.

Two options:

- If you're using C# 4 you could use dynamic typing. It doesn't give you compile-time safety, but it'll work if you're careful.
- You could use Marc Gravell's [generic operators](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/miscutil/usage/genericoperators.html) in [MiscUtil](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/miscutil)

Answer (score 0):

You can't statically restrict the function to only take floats or integers. To do so, you would have to check the argument types manually inside the function.