# How to create a generic class that can take SOME primitive types

Tags: c#, generics

I want to create a class like this

```
public class MyClass<T> where T:int || T:decimal || T:double || T:float ||T:long
{
public T DoSomething()
{}
}
```

Is it possible to do this in C#?

Comment: No, this is not supported in C#.

Comment: Do you mean that you want only number types ?

Comment: @paciv, yes that's what I want, in principle, since I will be doing some math on that.

Comment: Look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1348594/is-there-a-c-sharp-generic-constraint-for-real-number-types

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do this, but you can use `struct` constraint which means that type argument must be a value type:

```
public class MyClass<T> where T: struct
{
  public T DoSomething()
  {  
    // your code
  }
}
```

Take a look at [Constraints on Type Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: The thing is I don't want to allow MyClass<bool> since I am performing numeric operations...

Comment: It seems that this is similar to [Generic constraint to match numeric types](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3329576/generic-constraint-to-match-numeric-types)

Comment: Marc gravell's article referred in the question you suggested did it.  Thanks! here's the url. http://yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/genericoperators.html