# Help in creating Enum extension helper

Tags: c#, .net

Take this enum for example:

```
public enum PersonName : short
{
    Mike = 1,
    Robert= 2
}
```

I wnat to have en extension method like this:

> ```
> PersonName person = PersonName.Robert;
> short personId = person.GetId();
> //Instead of:
> short personId = (short)person;
> ```

Any idea how to implement this?

it need to be generic to int, short etc..., and to generic enums as well, not limited to PersonName.

Comment: This is not possible to do.  (You cannot constain a method based on an `enum`'s underlying type)

Comment: Why would you need an extension method to do this? Casting to the underlying type is already as easy as `(int) SomeEnum.SomeValue`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is completely impossible.

You cannot constrain a method based on an `enum`'s underlying type.

## Explanation:

Here is how you might try to do this:

```
public static TNumber GetId<TEnum, TNumber>(this TEnum val) 
       where TEnum : Enum 
       where TEnum based on TNumber
```

The first constraint is [unfortunately not allowed by C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1404077/is-there-a-workaround-for-generic-type-constraint-of-special-class-enum-in-c-3/1404093), and the second constraint is not supported by the CLR.

Comment: You can "sort of" (well, you create the effect) - http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/09/10/generic-constraints-for-enums-and-delegates.aspx

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7244/anyone-know-a-good-workaround-for-the-lack-of-an-enum-generic-constraint

Answer (score 2):

Well, its sort of possible, but on the flip side you will have to specify what the underlying type is:

```
public static T GetId<T>(this Enum value) 
                        where T : struct, IComparable, IFormattable, IConvertible
{
    return (T)Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(T));
}
```

since `System.Enum` is the base class of all enum types. Call it:

```
PersonName person = PersonName.Robert;
short personId = person.GetId<short>();
```

Since you can cast almost anything to `long`, you could even have this:

```
public static long GetId(this Enum value)
{
    return Convert.ToInt64(value);
}
```

and call:

```
PersonName person = PersonName.Robert;
long personId = person.GetId();
```

What is otherwise possible is to get an `object` instance returned, like this or so:

```
public static object GetId(this Enum value)
{
    return Convert.ChangeType(task, Enum.GetUnderlyingType(value.GetType()));
}

PersonName person = PersonName.Robert;
var personId = (short)person.GetId(); 
// but that sort of defeats the purpose isnt it?
```

All of which involves some sort of boxing and unboxing. The second approach looks better (you could even make it `int`, the standard type) and then the first.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should be able to define an extension method on the `PersonName` class:

```
public static class PersonExtensions // now that sounds weird...
{
    public static short GetID (this PersonName name)
    {
        return (short) name;
    }
}
```

*Side node: I somehow hope that the code in your question is overly simplified, as it does not seem quite right to implement a person repository as an enum :)*

Comment: I want it to be a generic. and of course this was an example :)

Comment: Sorry, didn't catch that in your question. I am afraid I am not sure what you mean by "generic" in this context, but it seems like others have figured it out :)

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason you can't turn it into a class?  It would probably make more sense in context of a class.

Comment: Good point. And how get the person-property name, using reflation? or each one should return dictionary? I'll think about it. bu the question still interesting to me.

Answer (score 0):

I would just use something like `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string,short>>` or `Dictionary<string,short>`... you can add your extensions to IDictionary or IEnumerable if you want.

Comment: That what I'm going to use by now. But about the question, this behavior I wanted a lot of time, but from my knowledge it not possible to achieve.