# C# generic method with integer constraint refuses to cast from integer to the generic type

Tags: c#, generics

If I have a generic method that is constrained to be type 'int' then surely I should be able to cast an integer to the generic T type. For example...

```
    public T ExampleMethod<T>(int unchanged) where T : int
    {
        return (T)unchanged;
    }
```

...the compiler complains that *Cannot convert type 'int' to 'T'* but I have a constraint indicating that the target is as integer. So surely it should work?

**Update:**

The actual scenario is that I want to a helper method that returns an enum value. So my ideal helper method would be more like this....

```
public T GetAttributeAsEnum<T>(XmlReader reader, string name) where T : enum
{
    string s = reader.GetAttribute(name);
    int i = int.Parse(s);
    return (T)i;
}
```

...and use it like this...

```
StateEnum x = GetAttributeAsEnum<StateEnum>(xmlReader, "State");
CategoryEnum y = GetAttributeAsEnum<CategoryEnum>(xmlReader, "Category");
OtherEnum z = GetAttributeAsEnum<OtherEnum>(xmlReader, "Other");
```

...but you cannot constrain by enum.

Comment: Why not just specify the parameter type as `T`?

Comment: My real situation is more complicated. I want a helper method tthat reads a string from a file, the string is actually a number. Then cast the number to the correct target enum type. So...

Comment: This will not compile. Error : 'int' is not a valid constraint. A type used as a constraint must be an interface, a non-sealed class or a type parameter.

Comment: If `T` is always int then why to use generics?

Comment: public T Method<T>(XmlReader reader) where T : enum
{
    string s = reader.GetAttribute("whatever");
    int i = int.Parse(s);
    return (T)i;
}

Comment: @PhilWright code in the question body: `where T : int`. Is it a typo?

Comment: @PhilWright, You might want to look at [Enum.ToObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ksbe1e7h.aspx)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/79126/create-generic-method-constraining-t-to-an-enum

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"*Only class or interface could be specified as constraint.*" (c) ReSharper

int (Int32) is just a struct. You can constrain that T is *a struct*. but you can't use any struct as constraint.

the whole list of possible constraints you can find here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx

**UPD**

and for Enum constraint see this question - [Is there a workaround for generic type constraint of "special class" Enum in C# 3.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1404077/is-there-a-workaround-for-generic-type-constraint-of-special-class-enum-in-c-s)

Comment: A *struct* can also be used as a constraint.  The following compiles: `public class Generic<T> where T : struct { }`.  You can then instantiate the class as `Generic<int> gen = new Generic<int>();`.

Comment: @EricJ. you don't understand. we can constrain T to be "a struct", but we can't use any struct as constraint.

Comment: I see where you are coming from.  As it stands, though, your answer is misleading.  You in addition to *struct* you can also specify *new* as a constraint.  Neither of those are a "class or interface".

Answer (score 4):

*int* (and all other numeric types, and enums) cannot be used as a generic constraint.

See

[Generic C# Code and the Plus Operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4039694/generic-c-sharp-code-and-the-plus-operator)

for further details and options.

For a discussion with Anders Hejlsberg, the creator of C#, about generics and type constraints see

http://www.artima.com/intv/generics.html

One can place a type constraint of *struct* like this:

```
public class Generic<T> where T : struct { }

Generic<int> gen = new Generic<int>();
```

Comment: **Downvoter**: What is wrong with this answer? Do share, so that we can all learn.

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure its compiling?

Here, it gives following error:

> error CS0701: 'int' is not a valid constraint. A type used as a
>   constraint must be an interface, a non-sealed class or a type
>   parameter.