# Can I cast from a generic type to an enum in C#?

Tags: c#, generics, casting, enums

I'm writing an utility function that gets a integer from the database and returns a typed enum to the application.

Here is what I tried to do (note I pass in a data reader and column name instead of the `int` in my real function):

```
public static T GetEnum<T>(int enumAsInt)
{
    Type enumType = typeof(T);

    Enum value = (Enum)Enum.ToObject(enumType, enumAsInt);
    if (Enum.IsDefined(enumType, value) == false)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException("Unable to convert value from database to the type: " + enumType.ToString());
    }

    return (T)value;
}
```

But it won't let me cast `(T)value` saying:

> Cannot convert type 'System.Enum' to 'T'.

Also I've read quite a bit of mixed reviews about using `Enum.IsDefined`. Performance wise it sounds very poor.  How else can I guarantee a valid value?

Comment: Note that if the case had been other way around, say, you have to do `(Enum)value` and you get `Cannot convert type 'T' to 'System.Enum'`, you could merely do an `as` cast, like `value as Enum`.

Comment: Not true (at least in my case), you get the old 'The as operator must be used with a reference or nullable type ('Foo.bar' is a non-nullable value type) error.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Like this:

```
return (T)(object)value;
```

Comment: It would be better to initially declare `value` as an `object`.

Comment: Thanks that seems to compile.  I don't understand the reason for the error then?  Bonus points if you can explain why in the interest of learning:)

Comment: The compiler doesn't realize that `T` is a enum type.  As far as it is aware, `T` might be `DateTime`.  Therefore, you cannot cast directly from any type other than `object` to `T`.

Comment: I did try to constrain T in the method signature with "where T : Enum".  But the compiler tells me Constraint cannot be special class 'System.Enum'.

Comment: @Justin: [Yes; this is an annoying and unnecessary limitation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1331739/enum-type-constraints-in-c/1416660#1416660)

Comment: Can't this be done without box-unbox? May be using this `__makeref` thing

Answer (score 21):

Change this:

```
Enum value = (Enum)Enum.ToObject(enumType, enumAsInt);
```

to this:

```
T value = (T)Enum.ToObject(enumType, enumAsInt);
```

and remove the cast :)

Comment: I couldn't get Slaks solution to work, but using the Enum.ToObject cast worked great.

Answer (score 2):

For information, using the generic constraint `Enum` is available from C# 7.3 and greater.

Comment: OMG, the best answer here (for my issue). Thanks a lot!