# Constraining a generic method using Enum methods to T

Tags: c#-4.0, enums, extension-methods

I've been trying to write a utility extension method for flagged enum values. The purpose with this method is to retrieve a list of all the flags that are currently enabled.

What I wanted to do was this:

```
 public static IEnumerable<T> GetFlags<T>(this T value) where T:Enum 
  {
     return Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)).OfType<Enum>().Where(value.HasFlag).Cast<T>(); 
  }
```

However, since generics doesn't work with the Enum type I had to resort to the following:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> GetFlags<T>(this Enum value) 
  {
     return Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)).OfType<Enum>().Where(value.HasFlag).Cast<T>(); 
  }
```

Is there any way to get around this or should I resign myself to explicitly having to declare the type every time the method is called ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1331739/enum-type-constraints-in-c

Comment: possible duplicate of [Anyone know a good workaround for the lack of an enum generic constraint?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7244/anyone-know-a-good-workaround-for-the-lack-of-an-enum-generic-constraint)

Answer (score 2):

The best you can do is `where T : struct`.

For non-extension methods, you can use an ugly trick:

```
public abstract class Enums<Temp> where Temp : class {
    public static TEnum Parse<TEnum>(string name) where TEnum : struct, Temp {
        return (TEnum)Enum.Parse(typeof(TEnum), name); 
    }
}
public abstract class Enums : Enums<Enum> { }

Enums.Parse<DateTimeKind>("Local")
```

If you want to, you can give `Enums<Temp>` a private constructor and a public nested abstract inherited class with `Temp` as `Enum`, to prevent inherited versions for non-enums.

You can't use this trick to make extension methods because extension methods must be defined in a `static` class and cannot inherit a different class.

Comment: It's not as ugly as some of the alternatives out there.  Pretty ingenious, actually.

Answer (score 0):

I use reflection. Just invoke the `HasFlag` (or whatever method you need) by yourself at runtime.

The `where` clause gives as much constraint as we can. Then, if your type is not an `enum`, this code will raise a `TargetInvocationException`.

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets the flags for the given enum value.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">The enum type</typeparam>
/// <param name="enumValue">The enum value.</param>
/// <returns>The flagged values.</returns>
public static IEnumerable<T> GetFlags<T>(this T enumValue)
    where T : struct
{
    Type enumType = enumValue.GetType();
    foreach (T value in Enum.GetValues(enumType))
    {
        bool hasFlag = (bool)enumType.InvokeMember("HasFlag", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, enumValue, new object[] { value });
        if (hasFlag)
        {
            yield return value;
        }
    }
}
```