# C# Generics: Enum constraints are not allowed, Why?

Tags: c#, generics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Enum type constraints in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1331739/enum-type-constraints-in-c)

Could somebody kindly explain to me with a *simple* sample and *simple* words why `enum` constraints are not allowed on a generic type i.e. What would happen if they were possible?

Comment: An enum is a value type, there aren't many constraints you could apply to a value type.  (only `struct` and `new()` comes to mind)

Comment: did you read this Q?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/79126/create-generic-method-constraining-t-to-an-enum

Comment: Take a look at this: https://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/09/10/generic-constraints-for-enums-and-delegates.aspx

Comment: Wanted something **very** simple and got it. thanks mates :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply put: because they're not.  That's how the language is designed (you wanted simple, right? :) )

`enum` is a value type, so you could put a restraint on your generic type `where T : struct` and use [Type.IsEnum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isenum%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) to check in the constructor, throwing an exception if it returns false.

Comment: Simple and straight forward, thanks Ed :-)

Comment: These are now supported in C# 7.3