# Using enum as generic type parameter in C#

Tags: c#, generics, enums

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Enum type constraints in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1331739/enum-type-constraints-in-c)

Is it possible to use `enum` types as a generic paramter by using its wrapper class `Enum`?

I have different enums:

```
enum errors1 { E1, E3, E8 };
enum errors2 { E0, E2, E9 };
enum errors3 { E7, E4, E5 };
```

With the following class declaration I thought I could achieve it:

```
public class MyErrors<T> where T : Enum
{
   T enumeration;

   public T getEnumeration()
   {
       return enumeration;
   }

   static void Main(string[] args)
   {

       Program<error1> p = new Program<error1>();
       p.getEnumeration().E1  // this call does NOT work
   }
```

However, since the general type is `Enum` I can only access the member and methods of the `Enum` class. So is it possible to implement it the way I meant to or what other approach should I use?

Comment: Introduced in C# 7.3: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters#enum-constraints

Comment: @Fildor The question is closed, I cannot add a new answer. The top linked question is also closed. Then the next linked question has an answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/50289291/617543. :-)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

No, it's not possible unfortunately. The best you can do is use `where T : struct, IComparable, IConvertible, IFormattable` (which of course is not the same). The interface restrictions are derived from the implementation of [`System.Enum`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.aspx).

Apart from that, you can check if `typeof(T).IsEnum`, which can detect the problem at runtime and presumably throw an exception. But there is no way to enforce this restriction at compile time.

Answer (score 12):

This is not doable at the language level in C#, but it's supported by the underlying CLR. You can use Jon Skeet's [Unconstrained Melody](http://code.google.com/p/unconstrained-melody/), which will transform the generated binary to one with the actual enum generic constraint.