# C# - Generic enum type casting

Tags: c#, generics, enums

I have a few questions about generic classes with `Enum`s.

First of all, I declared my class like this:

```
public class MyClass<TEnum> where TEnum : struct, IConvertible
```

But, I'm getting an error that states that my class cannot be used with type arguments.

Moreover, I need to convert the `Enum`'s value to an `Integer`. How can I do that?

```
public void SomeMethod(TEnum value)
{
    int a = (int)value; // Doesn't work, need to cast to Enum first (?).
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: For the first part see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438352/using-enum-as-generic-type-parameter-in-c-sharp

Comment: And where please is the Enum here?

Comment: For the second, you can't redeclare `value` inside the function because it's already a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You already have what you need since you declared requirement IConvertible. Just use ToInt32 etc methods:

```
public class MyClass<TEnum> where TEnum: struct, IConvertible
{        
    public int SomeMethod(TEnum value)
    {
        return value.ToInt32(null);
    }
}
```

For example .NET type decimal is a struct and an IConvertble:

```
MyClass<decimal> test = new MyClass<decimal>();
Console.WriteLine(test.SomeMethod(150m));
```

For other classes be sure that you implement IConvertible.

Answer (score 0):

You have declared your generic type parameter to implement `IConvertible` and that interface has a `ToInt32` method.

Comment: Hey, I know you from VBForums, hehe. I remember your dog avatar! Anyways, ToInt32 requires some FormatProvider...? Also, ToInt32 uses Convert. Isn't it easier to use Convert.ToInt32(value)?

Comment: You should be able to simply use `null` for the parameter value.  You probably can just as easily use `Convert.ToInt32`.