# Get description of enum value from T type

Tags: c#, enums

I'm trying to call `ToDescription` method on enum which is declared as `T`. Compiler won't accept this method as it doesn't know that `T` is an enum.

What I want to achieve is something like this:

```
public string FromDtoProperty(T source)
{
    return source.ToDescription();
}
```

Is there any way how to do this?

Comment: What is `ToDescription`? How this method defined?

Comment: What *is* the description of an enum value? In `enum E { A, B, C }` what is the description of `E.B`?

Comment: Is `ToDescription` an extension method for any given enum?

Comment: I'm guessing he might mean this: [System.ComponentModel.DescriptionAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.descriptionattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: You can return an enum value using its type with the static `Enum` class.  But a standard enum has no `ToDescription` property.

Comment: This question does not make sense without further explanation. There is no `ToDescription` method on [enum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: @zespri - It's an extension method.

Comment: @Smith.h.Neil that would be wrong too, there is no `ToDescription` extension method in BCL. Search MSDN if not sure. And if you (or OP) are using sone non-standard extension methods this information has to be included in the question, for the question to make sense.

Comment: @zespri - I meant it's his extension. I am assuming this is the case though... I sure hope it's his extension.

Comment: Ideally, you could do `where T : enum`. But this is not supported in C# yet. =( http://stackoverflow.com/a/79903/781792

Comment: @TimS. Good one! On a similar note, [that's why](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1331811/284111)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create Generic method constraining T to an Enum](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/79126/create-generic-method-constraining-t-to-an-enum)

Comment: There is a standard way to constrain a generic type to enum. See possible duplicate reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does that needs to be generic method? If not this should work.

```
public string FromDtoProperty(Enum source)
{
    return source.ToDescription();
}
```

If it has to be generic, then you can do

```
public string FromDtoProperty<T>(T source) where T : struct, IConvertible
{
    if (!typeof(T).IsEnum) 
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("T must be an enumerated type");
    }
    return ((Enum)(object)source).ToDescription();
}
```

Assuming `ToDescription` is an extension method defined for any `Enum`.

Comment: Ah so that's how to you get to `ToDescription` from `T`.

Comment: @Smith.h.Neil That's how we fool the compiler.

Comment: You have to constrain the generic type per http://stackoverflow.com/a/79903/380384

Comment: @ja72 That's not much useful for this question. Anyway thanks for pointing out.

Comment: That's what I wanted, thanks a lot! Sorry I've not made clear the ToDescription function is connected with  System.ComponentModel.DescriptionAttribute