# How to declare an Enum to be used by a generic type?

Tags: c#, generics

I would like to declare in a parent abstract class something along the lines of:

```
  public abstract void RefreshDisplay<TView>(Enum value);
```

Which would then be implemented in the child class like:

```
   public override void RefreshDisplay<RxViewModel>(RxViews view)
```

Where RxViews is an enumeration and "view" a specific value from that enumeration.

The actual view and Enum from which it came will not be known until run-time.

Can this be done?   I appreciate the help.

Edit: I may have asked this wrong. The TView is not an enumeration, but rather a view that inherits from ViewModelBase. (I don't see where this is a duplicate question?) Thanks.

Edit: I'm guessing this was fixed in net 4.5. Any ideas how to work around this in net 4.0?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1331739/enum-type-constraints-in-c-sharp

Comment: Why does your first snippet work for you?

Comment: Why don´t use two generic types, one for the viewModel and other for the Enum, like this: public abstract void RefreshDisplay<TView,TEnum>(TEnum value) where TEnum : Enum;

Comment: @Lombardo Error: "TEnum is a field but is used like a type" ??? Thanks.

Comment: @Servy "No suitable method found to override." I do not know how to generalize the child call on RefreshhDisplay in the parent. Thanks.

Comment: @Lombardo Can this be done in VS2010?

Comment: @Lombardo Umm.. Upon recompile, I now get "Constraint cannot be special class System.Enum" ??? (VS2010).

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do, even beyond the enum question.  You can't specify the generic type when you're overriding an abstract generic method.

Comment: @DaxFohl I have multiple different detail listings being shown in a common scroll viewer. The different lists are based on a specific values from an enumeration. I am trying to generalize the RefreshDisplay() in my viewmodel base so as it can be inherited by the specific views. (If not a good explanation I can give more detail).

Comment: You might use a custom class instead of an enum. The base class could be defined as Views<TView>, you inherit it for each TView and provides static instances for each value.

Comment: @Guillaume Could you give a short example? Thanks.

Comment: You'll have to make the base class generic on TView and TViewEnum, but you won't be able to operate on them generically because each subclass will have different generic params.  So I think you need to rethink your design, which is a whole other question.

Comment: @DaxFohl I'm new to this...Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: @AlanWayne no suggestions - that is not possible right-away (at least so far), have you read first link?

Comment: Hard to say without being there.  Don't get too carried away with type safety; it can be a good mental exercise to make everything fit but sometimes upcasting and asserting is more readable and pragmatic, and type theory itself has some loose edges anyway.

Comment: Also consider using java-style enums:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/469315/171121

Comment: @Vladimirs Yes. Discouraged :(

Comment: @DaxFohl I'm thinking this is a good example of what Guillaume meant? Thanks much.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The constraint type you need to use for generics with an `Enum` in .NET 4.0 is as follows - note you will need to change your class declaration for this to work correctly:

```
public abstract class BaseClass<TView, TEnum> 
    where TView: ViewModelBase
    where TEnum : struct,  IComparable, IFormattable, IConvertible
{

    public abstract void RefreshDisplay<TView, TEnum>(TEnum value);
}
```

You should however also do something similar to the following line in your implementation of the method:

```
if (!typeof(TEnum).IsEnum) { throw new ArgumentException("TEnum must be an enumerated type"); }
```

The type check is necessary due to not being 100% sure that it's an `Enum` (tho' `Enum` implements all those aspects which is why they are used).

You might want to consider rather making the method `virtual` and including that in the base method implementation.

Note that this code is adapted from the answer available here : [Create Generic method constraining T to an Enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79126/create-generic-method-constraining-t-to-an-enum)

Comment: How would he then specify the generic classes in the override method no the child class?

Comment: His class would become `class ViewModelBase<TView, TEnum>`.

Comment: Abstract methods cannot contain body!

Answer (score 0):

You might use a custom class instead of an enum. The base class could be defined as Views, you inherit it for each TView and provides static instances for each value.

```
public abstract class A
{
    public abstract void RefreshDisplay<TView>(Views<TView> value);
}

public abstract class Views<TView>
{
    internal Views() {} //Used to disallow inheriting from outside, not mandatory...

    //You can add other methods/properties to allow processing in RefreshDisplay method
}

public sealed class RxViews : Views<TView>
{
    private RxViews() {}

    private static readonly RxViews myFirstRxView = new RxViews();
    public static RxViews MyFirstRxView { get { return myFirstRxView; } }
}
```