# C# Interface with Enum Type Parameter

Tags: c#, .net, interface

Is it possible to pass an enum as a type parameter for an interface, or is there a way I can achieve the same thing a different way?

E.g.

```
public interface IServiceResponse<R, enumServiceID> {}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1331739/enum-type-constraints-in-c-sharp), which is already one of any duplicates of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7244/anyone-know-a-good-workaround-for-the-lack-of-an-enum-generic-constraint).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Anyone know a good workaround for the lack of an enum generic constraint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7244/anyone-know-a-good-workaround-for-the-lack-of-an-enum-generic-constraint)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're declaring the interface so the Type Parameters are symbolic representations of a type, not an actual concrete type. You can put a type parameter that you expect to be an enum type (say TEnum), and then constrain it to be a Value Type (where TEnum : struct), but, unfortunately you can't constrain it to be an enum. Once you do that, you can declare a class the implements that interface with a concrete enum type:

```
public class MyServiceResponse : IServiceResponse<MyRType, EnumServiceId> {  }
```

---

**UPDATE**

As noted by @BJMeyers in the comments, C# now supports `Enum` constraints on type parameters.  As a result, you can do something like this now:

```
public class MyServiceResponse : IServiceResponse<MyRType, TEnumService> where TEnumService : struct, System.Enum 
{
    public TEnumService EnumServiceId { get; set; }
    // ... more code here ...
}
```

I'm not sure if that's what you want, but if it is, you can do it.  Note, the `struct` in the `where` constraint is important (remember that System.Enum is a class, not a struct).

Comment: Noteworthy: C# 7.3 supports the `where T : Enum` constraint.

Comment: Alleluia. I've silently asked for that so many times over the years. Thanks for letting me know!

Comment: @BJMyers Finally, glad to have learned that, been long overdue. Now all we need is "numeric" type constraints...