# How to represent an Enum in an Interface?

Tags: c#, enums, interface

How could I define an Interface which has a method that has `Enum` as a paramater when enums cannot be defined in an interface?

For an `Enum` is not a reference type so an `Object` type cannot be used as the type for the incoming param, so how then?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
interface MyInterface
{
    void MyMethod(Enum @enum);
}
```

Comment: what's the @ for?  I tried to look it up in MSDN...sorry if this seems trivial.  I'm new to creating interfaces.

Comment: anticipating your question:  `@enum` is the name of the variable.  There is nothing special about that syntax

Comment: @coffeeaddict: It allows you to use a reserved word for a parameter name.  Without it, you'd get a compiler error (unless you rename "enum" to something else)

Comment: still Enum is a type declared in a different namespace even. 
The Enum type is yet declared outside an interface.

Comment: Am wondering whether this accepted answer is what the user who posted this question is looking for?

Comment: A clearer example would have not used the @ symbol at all because it is confusing to everyone except more advanced, senior, and principle developers. I have no idea how this wound up being the accepted answer over the one above it. The one above it is clear, concise, and less confusing for the general audience.

Answer (score 50):

```
public enum MyEnum
{
  Hurr,
  Durr
}

public interface MyInterface
{
  void MyMethod(MyEnum value);
}
```

If this isn't what you're talking about doing, leave a comment so people can understand what your issue is.  Because, while the enum isn't defined within the interface, this is a completely normal and acceptable design.

Comment: +1 I created an iEventLogTypes `class` as helper for my IEventLog `interface`.  Right now it only contains an `enum`, but I can add any "types" that I need within my interface.  I like sticking the enum in a "similar named" class so that the enum is more tightly bound to the specific interface, even if it's in "name only".

Comment: I don't know why, but I never thought of creating the Enum outside of the class declaration, but within the namespace before.

Answer (score 10):

Another solution could be to use Generic types:

```
public enum MyEnum
{
    Foo,
    Bar
}

public interface IDummy<EnumType>
{
    void OneMethod(EnumType enumVar);
}

public class Dummy : IDummy<MyEnum>
{
    public void OneMethod(MyEnum enumVar)
    {
        // Your code
    }
}
```

Also, since C# 7.3, you can add a generic constraint to accept only Enum types:

```
public interface IDummy<EnumType> where EnumType : Enum
{
    void OneMethod(EnumType enumVar);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Defining an enum is like defining a class or defining an interface. You could just put it in one of your class files, inside the namespace but outside the class definition, but if several classes use it, which one do you put it in, and whichever you choose you will get "Type name does not match file name" warnings. So the "right" way to do it is to put it in its own file, as you would a class or an interface:

MyEnum.cs

`namespace MyNamespace
{
    internal enum MyEnum { Value1, Value2, Value3, Value4, Value5 };
}`

Then any interfaces or classes within the namespace can access it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about generic interfaces and the fact that C# doesn't let you constrain generic types to be enums, the [answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3153217/c-enums-in-interfaces/3153599#3153599) include two different work-arounds.

Comment: It does constrain, you just can't define the type inside the interface.
The same way you do when you create an interface, add a namespace that contain a specific type then add that in the parameters or return types.

Answer (score 0):

You must implement the enum in both side and refer the Interface namespace, eg:

```
public interface IConfigProvider
{
    enum OUType
    {
        Prop1,
        Prop2
    };


    string GetConfig(OUType outType);
}

public class ConfigProvider
{
    enum OUType
    {
       Prop1,
       Prop2
    };
    
    public string GetConfig(IConfigProvider.OUType outType)
    {
        ...
    }
    
}
```

Usage:

```
configProvider.GetConfig(IConfigProvider.OUType.Prop1)
```