# How to Implement Interface with Enum Specific to Derived Class in C#?

Tags: c#, inheritance, enums, interface

I'm trying to write an interface such as...

```
interface MyInterface
{
    MyObject Set(REGISTER register, PIN pin);
}
```

Both `REGISTER` and `PIN` are enums.  The problem I'm running into is that `REGISTER` is defined in my `MyBaseClass` and `PIN` is defined in `MyDerivedClass`.  I can live with using something like `MyBaseClass.REGISTER` in the interface, but that won't work for `PIN`.  Every derivation of `MyBaseClass` will have a different enumeration for `PIN`.  I found [this other answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3216355/214296), which seems to partially solve the problem, but it's not clear how I should then implement the function in `MyDerivedClass`.  Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: Why wouldnt your enums just be in their own files and not defined inside a class?  Or am I misunderstanding

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using generics:

```
interface MyInterface<TPin>
{
    MyObject Set(Register register, TPin pin);
}
```

When you implement it in each derived class, you have to tell it what the type of the pin enum is:

```
class MyImplementation : MyInterface<MyPin>
{
    MyObject Set(Register register, MyPin pin)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

This means that you can't have a list of `MyInterface` objects, but you can have a list of `MyInterface<SomePin>` objects. And that makes sense - if the enum is different for each implementation, then given a `MyInterface`, how would you know what values to pass it?