# Enum Extension generating garbage

Tags: c#, enums, garbage-collection, garbage

I have the following;

```
public static bool Has<T>(this System.Enum type, T value) where T : struct
{
    return (((int)(ValueType)type & (int)(ValueType)value) == (int)(ValueType)value);
}
```

For some reason, calling this extension method is generating garbage, and I simply can't see why. Everything here is struct or values. Where is that unseen garbage? Is there some not-so-obvious boxing going on? Is there a better way to do this extension method?

Comment: What does "generating garbage" mean? Can you list some values going in and what values come out, plus what values you expected to come out?

Comment: By "Generating Garbage" do you mean it's returning invalid results, or it's creating things for the garbage collector?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain It generates object that are only used in this scope, and is collected by the GC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Casting to `ValueType` effectively boxes the object (note that [`ValueType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.valuetype(v=vs.110).aspx), while the "base class for value types", is a *class*), and then the cast to `int` unboxes it.  This will also fail if the underlying type of the enum happens to be something other than `Int32`, which is also possible.

You should be able to use [`Enum.HasFlag`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.hasflag(v=vs.110).aspx) to accomplish this same functionality without a custom method.

Comment: I'm stuck in .NET <3.5, which does not have Enum.HasFlag. Is there an alternative that would not involve boxing?

Comment: Take a look at this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4108828/generic-extension-method-to-see-if-an-enum-contains-a-flag

Comment: @EtienneMaheu Sadly, using Convert to turn an Enum into a ulong also generates garbage. I have a feeling I'm going to be stuck with it.

Comment: What do you mean by "garbage"? What kind of "garbage" do you get? This code works perfectly well for me so I find it strange that it does not work in your case. Can you post your enum's definition?

Comment: @EtienneMaheu I never said it's not working, it's working perfectly fine! I mean garbage as in what the Garbage Collector eats for breakfast; object instances with no references towards them.

Comment: Note that `Enum.HasFlag` will still generate some garbage because its argument is of type `System.Enum` which is a class and so the argument will be boxed.

Comment: @LightStriker Just going to Enum will create some garbage.  That's pretty much part of life with this..

Comment: @mikez True - though it doesn't do as many boxes and unboxes as this, from what I recall

Comment: Well the link I shared use decompiled code from the .NET framework so I would expect the native HasFlag method to be as boxing-intensive as this version.

Comment: @EtienneMaheu Current framework handles this in native code to make it better.  See: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/enum.cs#820

Comment: Well, thanks for all the information. From what I understand, I simply cannot avoid generating garbage from an extension method for an Enum, I can only try to minimized it. I guess I'll have to live with it.

Comment: @ReedCopsey I count three boxes here (although it could be two if a local variable is used). Looking at the reference source, I see another box for `this.GetType()` so that's two boxing operations for each call to `Enum.HasFlag`.

Comment: @LightStriker There is no good way to do it in general. However, you might consider writing extension methods on the specific enums where you have memory pressure/performance concerns.

Comment: @LightStriker and/or just use normal methods ;)