# Function that accepts mutliple, but specified enums

Tags: c#, enums, type-safety

How can I restrict a function argument to a some specific enums? Preferably check it at compile-time (though I doubt this is possible).

What I have are 2 enums (`KeyCode` for keyboard keys and `Mouse.Button` for mouse buttons) and they are treated in the code in exactly the same way. I could simply overload the function and copy-paste the contents, but well, I'd like to avoid the nightmares.

Simplified version of what I currently have (inside a class)

```
enum E1 { Zero, One, Two }
enum E2 { Three, Four, Five }

// Overloads so users can only use this with enums only of type E1 or E2
public void DoEnumStuff(E1 e) {
    DoEnumStuffTemplate(e);
}
public void DoEnumStuff(E2 e) {
    DoEnumStuffTemplate(e);
}

// private function so users cannot access this generic one
private void DoEnumStuffTemplate<T>(T e) where T : struct, IConvertible {
    // check type for safety
    if (!typeof(T).IsEnum || typeof(T).Name != "E1" || typeof(T).Name != "E2")
        throw new ArgumentException();

    // do lots of stuff
    DoSomething(e); //<- overloaded function, accepts only E1 and E2 =ERROR
    // do lots of other stuff
}
```

For completeness sake:

- `DoSomething` behaves completely different depending on which type is given
- `DoSomething` is called a lot in the function
- I cannot change the Enums
- I do not want to change `DoSomething`

---

I think I need to be able to tell the compiler that the generic `T` is surely either `E1` or `E2`, but I have no clue as of how to do this.

---

---

**Edit: the situation**

Lots of good suggestions, but nothing that encompasses all I want. I'll add here the code I currently have to shed some more light on the problem hopefully.

I'm making a minesweeper clone to try out Unity 2D. I've created an `Action` class based on the [`thor::ActionMap`](http://www.bromeon.ch/libraries/thor/tutorials/v2.0/actions.html) class from the library Thor in C++ used with [SFML](http://www.sfml-dev.org/). It simply allows for neat code such as (in C++)

```
ActionMap actionMap<string>;
actionMap["Fire"] = Action(Keyboard::LeftControl) || Action(Mouse::Left);
// stuff
while (game.IsRunning()) {
    if (actionMap["Fire"].IsActive()) //true if left control or left mouse button is held
        // FIRE
    // probably more stuff
}
```

Where `ActionMap` is simply a dictionary of a key (here a `string`) and an `Action`. As you can see, the `Action` accepts both keyboard and mouse buttons which are 2 different `enum`s. Thus the equivalent of the `DoSomething(e)` from the example code.

I'm now creating a method that can change the controls consistently. It uses the `enum` `EControls` as key instead of a `string`. Here `KeyCode` contains all keyboard keys and `Mouse.Button` all the mouse buttons. I need to differentiate between pressing and releasing of a button here, which is why both `EControls.TilePressed` and `EControls.TileReleased` will have the same key and need to be treated differently than for example `EControls.GameEscape`. This code is again in C#.

```
private ActionMap _controls = new ActionMap<EControls>();

// Set controls for a keyboard key
public void SetControl(EControls control, KeyCode key) {
    switch (control) {
        // If either TilePressed or Released was given, set them both to the same key
        case EControls.TilePressed:
        case EControls.TileReleased:
            //Here Action(...) is DoSomething(...) from the example code
            _controls[EControls.TilePressed] = new Action(key, Action.EActionType.PressOnce);
            _controls[EControls.TileReleased] = new Action(key, Action.EActionType.ReleaseOnce);
            break;
        case EControls.TileFlagPressed:
        case EControls.TileFlagReleased:
            _controls[EControls.TileFlagPressed] = new Action(key, Action.EActionType.PressOnce);
            _controls[EControls.TileFlagReleased] = new Action(key, Action.EActionType.ReleaseOnce);
            break;
        case EControls.GameEscape:
            _controls[EControls.GameEscape] = new Action(key, Action.EActionType.ReleaseOnce);
            break;
        default:
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("control");
    }
}

// Set controls for a mouse button
public void SetControl(EControls control, Mouse.Button button) {
    // copy-pasted code :(
    case EControls.TilePressed:
        case EControls.TileReleased:
            _controls[EControls.TilePressed] = new Action(button, Action.EActionType.PressOnce);
            _controls[EControls.TileReleased] = new Action(button, Action.EActionType.ReleaseOnce);
            break;
        case EControls.TileFlagPressed:
        case EControls.TileFlagReleased:
            _controls[EControls.TileFlagPressed] = new Action(button, Action.EActionType.PressOnce);
            _controls[EControls.TileFlagReleased] = new Action(button, Action.EActionType.ReleaseOnce);
            break;
        case EControls.GameEscape:
            _controls[EControls.GameEscape] = new Action(button, Action.EActionType.ReleaseOnce);
            break;
        default:
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("control");
    }
}
```

As you can see, in almost every line of code `new Action(...)` is present and code such as `if (typeof(T).GetType() == typeof(E1))` is essentially the same as copy-pasting the contents of the function. Which is something I'd like to avoid (copy-pasting would even be safer on compile-time). But as it stands, it does not seem to be possible.

Since in a bigger game you'll probably regularly add some new controls, it will be quite an annoyance.

Sorry for the wall of text :s

Comment: Overloading is okay I think.... That is what it is specifically designed for.. why do you think it is bad?

Comment: if `DoSomething` behaves differently for different types, why force things into a single method?  Just overload and use two separate methods.

Comment: `"I'd like to avoid the nightmares"` - Nightmares such as... what, exactly?  Method overloading is a pretty straightforward part of the language.  Duplicated concerns can be refactored pretty easily.

Comment: You should consider replacing != "E1" with typeof(E1) etc. Also  I would suggest to do all the common stuff in private method that receives int and call it inside each overload of DoSomething(e) and remove DoEnumStuffTemplate completely

Comment: I don't want the copy-pasta since the function is quite long and will need regular updates. It's the copy-paste I can get nightmares from, not from method overloading.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5067724/1997232) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/79126/1997232) regarding your last edit.

Comment: @Sinatr I want to restrict the types to only `E1` and `E2`, not all enums (or `struct`s/`IConvertible`s in the case you mentioned). I read about John Skeet's `UnconstrainedMelody`, and I not fully understand it, but I think this does the same.

Comment: .GetType() calls are incorrect. typeof(T).Name is all you need.

Comment: BTW: Seems that the `ActionMap` and `SetControl` functionality is an alternative implementation of Unity's Input.GetAxis("Vertical") stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a refactoring that resembles the Factory pattern:

```
public void SetControl(EControls control, Func<Action.EActionType, Action> createAction)
{
    switch (control)
    {
        case EControls.TilePressed:
        case EControls.TileReleased:
            _controls[EControls.TilePressed] = createAction(Action.EActionType.PressOnce);
            _controls[EControls.TileReleased] = createAction(Action.EActionType.ReleaseOnce);
            break;

        case EControls.TileFlagPressed:
        case EControls.TileFlagReleased:
            _controls[EControls.TileFlagPressed] = createAction(Action.EActionType.PressOnce);
            _controls[EControls.TileFlagReleased] = createAction(Action.EActionType.ReleaseOnce);
            break;

        case EControls.GameEscape:
            _controls[EControls.GameEscape] = createAction(Action.EActionType.ReleaseOnce);
            break;

        default:
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("control");
    }
}

// Call it later with:
SetControl(control, type => new Action(key, type));
SetControl(control, type => new Action(mouseButton, type));
```

You provide `SetControl` with what amounts to a partially filled constructor, `createAction`, that only needs the `EActionType` to fully create the `Action`.

Another way to do this (while changing more code) would be to invert the dependency: give the `Action` a way to set its own `EActionType` based on a passed in `EControls`.

Answer (score 1):

I think overloading is your best bet.  Factor `do lots of stuff` and `do lots of other stuff` into methods of their own, and you won't have any nightmares.

If that's really impossible, then what you have is fine.  Just cast `e` to either `E1` or `E2` as appropriate.  It's a little gross, but it's a private method so the ugliness shouldn't spread too far.

Comment: But, the `do lots of stuff` also contains lots of `DoSomething`s actually. Should have mentioned this though.
And I cannot cast to `E1` or `E2` because I don't know which type they are inside the function. If I could, there shouldn't be any problem :-)

Comment: @Didii There should still be a way, maybe even passing `Action`s into sub-methods or splitting up the segments that don't use `DoSomething` better. Perhaps you should write out your code once and put it on Code Review to see what people think of your concrete case?

Comment: @31eee384 I've added the code I'm using. I hope that makes things more clear of why I don't like the copy-paste and why the casting to `E1` or `E2` is essentially the same as the copy-paste.

Answer (score 1):

An ugly, but a way:

```
private void DoEnumStuffTemplate<T>(T e) where T : struct, IConvertible
{
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(E1))
        DoEnumStuff((E1)(object)e);
    else if (typeof(T) == typeof(E2))
        DoEnumStuff((E2)(object)e);
    else
        throw new ArgumentException();
}
```

Make sure nobody see it.

Comment: This is just method overloading in disguise :p I guess I need to do it the copy-paste way :(

Comment: No no, it's **generic** method, look at its signature! ;) I only wrote it because of your comment *"I cannot cast to `E1` or `E2` because I don't know which type they are inside the function"* (and ugly check in the question).

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to change `DoSomething`, but would wrapping it be ok?

```
private void myDoSomething(T e) where T : struct, IConvertible
{
    if (typeof(T).GetType().Name == "E1")
        DoSomething((E1)(object)e);
    else if (typeof(T).GetType().Name == "E2")
        DoSomething((E2)(object)e);
    else
        throw new ArgumentException();
}


// private function so users cannot access this generic one
private void DoEnumStuffTemplate<T>(T e) where T : struct, IConvertible {
    // check type for safety
    if (!typeof(T).IsEnum || typeof(T).GetType().Name != "E1" || typeof(T).GetType().Name != "E2")
        throw new ArgumentException();

    // do lots of stuff
    myDoSomething(e); //<- overloaded function, accepts only E1 and E2 =ERROR
    // do lots of other stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the `Action` in two steps. The caller of `SetControl(...)` knows whether the source is a mouse button or a key. So the caller creates the action object like `new Action(key)` or `new Action(button)`.
This action object is passed to the `SetControl(control, Action action)` method.
SetControl knows the action type. It needs a method in `Action` where the action type can be set, e.g. `Action.SetActionType(Action.EActionType actionType)`.

So the `SetControl` method is:

```
// Set controls for an action
public void SetControl(EControls control, Action action) {
    switch (control) {
        // If either TilePressed or Released was given, set them both to the same key
        case EControls.TilePressed:
        case EControls.TileReleased:
            //Here Action(...) is DoSomething(...) from the example code
            _controls[EControls.TilePressed] = action.SetActionType(Action.EActionType.PressOnce);
            _controls[EControls.TileReleased] = action.SetActionType(Action.EActionType.ReleaseOnce);
            break;
        case EControls.TileFlagPressed:
        case EControls.TileFlagReleased:
            _controls[EControls.TileFlagPressed] = action.SetActionType(Action.EActionType.PressOnce);
            _controls[EControls.TileFlagReleased] = action.SetActionType(Action.EActionType.ReleaseOnce);
            break;
        case EControls.GameEscape:
            _controls[EControls.GameEscape] = action.SetActionType(Action.EActionType.ReleaseOnce);
            break;
        default:
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("control");
    }
}
```

This method is called like so:

```
SetControl(control, new Action(key));
SetControl(control, new Action(mouseButton));
```