# How to constraint a generic to be of type enum?

Tags: c#, generics, type-constraints

Consider the following code:

```
class Base<T>
{
 //Base members
}
```

I want the generic T to be an enum (using constraints if possible). How can I do this in C#?

**EDIT:**
Using code contracts -introduced by Akash Kava- also seems like a nice way. I managed to get it to produce a run time error which is useless.  [Here](http://codeviewer.org/view/code:2185)'s the code I tried. It should be possible to generate a compile time warning but I can't get it to work.

Comment: Lots of them, but one of the canonical ones I can find is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/79126/create-generic-method-constraining-t-to-an-enum, which although is about a generic method, not a generic class, type constraints work in exactly the same way anyway.

Comment: @BoltClock, Thanks for pointing out, but I still got a very different answer (I think a better one). However, I haven't still managed to get it to work.

Comment: Have you tried code contracts?

Comment: @AkashKava: Never heard of 'em. Any links?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/dd491992 , this is little alternative way of creating warnings..

Comment: @AkashKava, Alright I read into it a bit. If I get it right I should check T to be of type enum in a precondition? Right?

Comment: Yes, but I don't know how to do it exactly but looks like it is possible to generate some warning.

Comment: @AkashKava, I managed to get it to check it at run time which is useless. I updated my post with the code I tried.

Comment: @AkashKava: I made it work. If you add an answer I'll vote it up.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Anyone know a good workaround for the lack of an enum generic constraint?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7244/anyone-know-a-good-workaround-for-the-lack-of-an-enum-generic-constraint)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is supported at the IL level but not in C#. You may take a look at [unconstrained melody](http://code.google.com/p/unconstrained-melody/) written by Jon Skeet which allows you to achieve that. And here's the corresponding [blog post](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2009/09/10/generic-constraints-for-enums-and-delegates/) where he explains in details.

Comment: Surprised there is no way in C#. :(

Comment: Out of curiosity, does the IL allow an enum-constrained generic to do anything an unconstrained generic can do other than invoke the slow `Enum.HasFlag`?  My guess would be that the C# crew judged the level of IL support to be unsufficient for what people would want to do with enum-constrained generics, and thought (misguidedly IMHO) that it would be better to disallow them than to allow them but not have them be able to do much.

Comment: There's [ExtraConstraints.Fody](https://github.com/Fody/ExtraConstraints) to achieve all the IL-weaving in a very simple way. Just install the nuget packages `Fody` and `ExtraConstraints.Fody` and add the constraints to the code as shown on the repo. Maybe you would want to add this to the answer?

Answer (score 1):

.NET 4.0 onwards you can create warnings by using Code Contracts, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/dd491992, this will let you check some preconditions and display warnings to developer.