# Possible to constrain generic type to enums?

Tags: c#, generics, enums

I have a generic class `Foo<T>` where I want to constrain `T` to be an `enum` type. Is this possible in *C#*?

I have tried

```
public class Foo<T> where T : enum   // COMPILATION ERROR
```

but this approach only seem to work for `class` and `struct`.

Likewise, attempting to constrain `T` to an underlying `enum` type will also not work:

```
public class Foo<T> where T : int    // COMPILATION ERROR
```

since `int` is not a class or interface.

---

**EDIT** I realize now that similar questions have been posted before, and eventually this question can be removed. One question that is even more related to my question, and that also contains the same answer as below, is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14160669/650012).

**UPDATE SEP 13, 2018** In the latest minor C# version, 7.3, it is now possible to constrain the generic type to an `Enum`. For more details, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/where-generic-type-constraint).

Comment: You are right. I will remove this question. Thanks anyway to those of you who have provided informative answers.

Comment: @AndersGustafsson Fair play.

Comment: @OndrejJanacek Just to be sure, you mean this in a non-ironic way, right? In that case, thanks. I *am* a little concerned about removing the question since other people have received upvotes on their answers.

Comment: @AndersGustafsson Yes, it is not irony. Your question will be removed sooner or later so why bother mods when you realize your mistake and you can remove it yourself?

Comment: @Ondrej Just for the record, it turned out that I cannot remove it myself since it already has received an answer. I *have* flagged it for deletion though, so it will go away eventually :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That isn't valid in the C# spec and implementation, but it *is* in IL.

Jon Skeet made a library to get around this called Unconstrained Melody:

https://code.google.com/p/unconstrained-melody/

Though I've never used it so I cannot offer any insight into how to take advantage of this.

Comment: many thanks for pointing this out. Since my question obviously has been stated before, I will remove the question though. Hope you are OK with that.

Comment: @AndersGustafsson but this answer hasn't been given before, has it? I'd say, don't delete the question

Comment: @dcastro Actually, it has, although not in the referred question above, I think. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14160744/650012) is one answer that I found. I will try to add that question to the post above.