# How to iterate through "set" enum in .NET C# 3.5

Tags: c#, .net, .net-3.5, enums, bit-manipulation

I know in .NET 4 you can use HasFlag

Is there any alternative to the following in .NET 3.5?

```
if ((enumVar & EnumType.ValueOne) == EnumType.ValueOne)
{
  // someMethod(1) or someMethod(EnumType.ValueOne)
}
if ((enumVar & EnumType.ValueTwo) == EnumType.ValueTwo)
{
  // someMethod(2) or someMethod(EnumType.ValueTwo)
}
if ((enumVar & EnumType.ValueThree) == EnumType.ValueThree)
{
  // someMethod(3) or someMethod(EnumType.ValueThree)
}
if ((enumVar & EnumType.ValueFour) == EnumType.ValueFour)
{
  // someMethod(4) or someMethod(EnumType.ValueFour)
}
```

...etc for each value in the enum? You must be able to use a for..each loop to accomplish this where the argument to someMethod is the index of the loop?

```
[Flags]
enum EnumType
{
  ValueOne = 1
  , ValueTwo = 2
  , ValueThree = 4
  , ValueFour = 8
}
```

**EDIT: Only worth looking at the accepted answer, the rest of the comments/answers can be safely ignored.**

Comment: why not just use a switch/case statement?

Comment: so are you admitting it can't be done in a loop?

Comment: youre not using a loop youre using if's...

Comment: @RhysW thats the whole point. I gave ifs and asked if they could be rewritten as a loop

Comment: Apologies, i assumed youre reply was directed at Chris, did not see the loop requirement

Comment: It was directed at Chris, as he suggested using switch/case

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to write something like this. You can make it generic if you want, but there's no way to set the constraint to be enum, so you'd have to check that yourself with reflection.

```
public static bool HasFlag(YourEnum source, YourEnum flag)
{
    return (source & flag) == flag;
}
```

Comment: shame about that, I guess its why hasFlag was introduced

Comment: @GregT If you "cheat", you can constrain to an enum. See [another answer in another thread](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1409873/1336654) where the project Unconstrained Melody is linked.

Answer (score 3):

```
foreach (EnumType enumType in Enum.GetValues(typeof(EnumType)))
{
    if(enumVar.HasFlag(enumType)) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine(enumTpye.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: I did say not to use HasFlag - this is .NET 3.5

Comment: Apologies - didn't read that. In which case you need to use the & operator.

Comment: @lazyberezovsky HasFlag was introduced in .net 4 he is using an earlier version

Comment: if(enumVar & enumType){...} should produce the same result as hasFlag

Comment: yes, but HasFlag can be parameterized but the other notation cannot, so cannot be done in a loop

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this to do a foreach loop of EnumType

```
foreach (EnumType enumType in Enum.GetValues(typeof(EnumType)))
{
    if (enumType.HasFlag(enumType))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(enumType.ToString());
    }
}
```

This will return ValueOne, ValueTwo, ValueThree.. etch 
not sure if this is what you are looking for please test and let me as well as others know

Comment: That doesn't check whether the enum value is set?

Comment: You could add a conditional statement in that loop I hope that I am understanding  your question correctly.. you could also add a Switch statement if you like

Comment: can you give example code? it can't use HasFlag as this is .NET 3.5

Comment: GregT I misunderstood your question I gave an answer that would return the values of the EnumType in a forloop I apologize

Answer (score 0):

```
switch enumvar
{
case valueOne:
{
//do some thing
breake;
}
case valuetwo:
{
//do some thing else
break;
}
default:
break;
    }
```