# The type of an enum

Tags: c#, enums

I'm trying to make a generic method from this method:

```
public static SelectList LanguagesToSelectList()
{
   return new SelectList(
        Enum.GetValues(typeof(Languages))
        .Cast<Languages>()
        .Select(g => new KeyValuePair<Languages, string>(
            g,
            Resources.Views_GamesAndApplications.ResourceManager.GetString("Language_" + g.ToString()
            )
        )), 
        "Key", 
        "Value"
        );
}
```

Here's what I got:

```
public static SelectList ToSelectList(Enum enumType, ResourceManager resourceManager, string resourcePrefix)
{
    return new SelectList(
        Enum.GetValues(typeof(enumType))
        .Cast<enumType>()
        .Select(g => new KeyValuePair<enumType, string>(
            g,
            resourceManager.GetString(resourcePrefix + g.ToString())
            )), 
        "Key", 
        "Value");
}
```

However, enumType shouldn't be of type `Enum` (nor should it be of type `Type`), and I can't figure out of what type is SHOULD be, or if I should rephrase the entire method..

Usage example (compliant with given answer):

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    m => m.Language,  
    SelectListHelper.ToSelectList<Languages>   
      (Resources.Views_GamesAndApplications.ResourceManager,"Language_"))
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public static SelectList ToSelectList<T>(ResourceManager resourceManager, string resourcePrefix)
    where T : struct 
{
    return new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)).Cast<T>()
                .Select(g => new KeyValuePair<T, string>(g, resourceManager.GetString(resourcePrefix + g.ToString()))), "Key", "Value");
}  

//Example:
var list = ToSelectList<Languages>(someResourceManager, "somePrefix");
```

Comment: Maybe you can add a small example about how you can call this method? That said, you should add a [constraint to ensure T is an enum](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1409873/588868).

Comment: You need to return the created list (I know the asker forgot that as well). I don't know why they don't make a generic version of `Enum.GetValues`. Instead of `.Cast<T>()` you can also say `((T[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)))` (or in this case just unbox when you create the `KeyValuePair<,>`).