# Can not cast integer to Enum in Generic method

Tags: c#, generics, enums, unconstrained-melody

I found c# does not allow generic type to be enum, so I did some research online and find this thread [Anyone know a good workaround for the lack of an enum generic constraint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7244/anyone-know-a-good-workaround-for-the-lack-of-an-enum-generic-constraint), then I installed the nuget package, but in my extension method, `(T)x.ToInteger()` throws can not convert type 'int' to 'T'. Thus `GetDescription()` won't work either, because it is my another enum extension method to get description of enum value. If I replace 'T' with a specified Enum, the following code will work. Any help is appreciated.
Here is my extension methos:

```
public static string ToEnumDescription<T>(this string enumValue) 
    where T: struct, IEnumConstraint
{
    if (enumValue.IsNullOrEmpty()) return string.Empty;
    var list = enumValue.Split(',');
    var descriptionList = new List<String>();
    foreach (var x in list)
    {
        var description = (x.IsInteger() && Enum.IsDefined(typeof(T), x.ToInteger())) 
            ? ((T)x.ToInteger()).GetDescription() 
            : string.Empty;
        descriptionList.Add(description);
    }
    return descriptionList.ToCommaSeperatedNoQuote();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a workaround, instead of `(T)x.ToInteger()` you should be able to do: `(T)(object)x.ToInteger()`.

This involves boxing and unboxing the value but that most likely is not a significant performance issue here.

Comment: Wonderful, now I can convert int to T, but 'T' must be convert into System.Enum before I can use GetDescription() extension method.